# PGFplot to occupy full \linewidth, and aligned y=axis across tikzpicture

Tags: spacing, pgfplots

How do I get the tikzpicture to occupy the full `\linewidth`, and also have the left and right axis aligned? I suspect that some `\phantom` spacing applied to the tick labels will do the trick, but don't know how to do that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/MyAxisStyle/.style={xmin=0,xmax=5, ymin=0,ymax=3,height=6cm,width=\linewidth}}
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/MyLineStyle/.style={samples=50, smooth, ultra thick}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}\centering
\hrule% To see actual \linewidth
\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[MyAxisStyle, xmax=10, ymax=110]
    \addplot[MyLineStyle, domain=0:10, ,red] {(x^2)} node [left] {$y=x^2$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[MyAxisStyle, xmax=2,ymax=9]
    \addplot[MyLineStyle, domain=0:2 ,green] {(x)^3} node [left] {$y=x^3$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[MyAxisStyle, width=0.5\linewidth]
    \addplot[MyLineStyle, domain=0:5, blue] {sqrt(x)} node [above left] {$y=\sqrt{x}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[MyAxisStyle, height=4cm,width=0.5\linewidth]
    \addplot[MyLineStyle, domain=0:5, blue] {sqrt(x)} node [above left] {$y=\sqrt{x}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hrule% To see actual \linewidth
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Note that in graphs 1 and 2 the y-axis are not aligned, and that they don't quite occupy the full `\linewidth` as shown by the horizontal rule.

[image]

Also, on the last two graphs I applied `width=0.5\linewidth`, and expected that the `\hfill` should have no effect, but end up with significant horizontal space in between the two graphs.

I am not using the `figure` environment as I don't want to have these float, so instead I use a `\minipage` and apply `\centering`.

I don't want to use [Scale TikZ figure to linewidth when relative positioning used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17293/scale-tikz-figure-to-linewidth-when-relative-positioning-used) as that will scale the text as well nor do I want to scale the picture as in [How to scale a tikzpicture to \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/how-to-scale-a-tikzpicture-to-textwidth), but rather get the graph to use the full width

Answer (score 26, accepted):

PGFplots has to estimate the space taken up by the labels, which is not easy and can lead to the plot having a different size than the one specified using `width`. In this case, I would use the option `scale only axis`, which applies the `width` and `height` options only to the axis, not the whole plot including the labels.

While this means you have to manually choose a `width` that's a bit smaller than your overall intended plot width, it makes the alignment of the plots a lot easier, since you now know that both large plot axes have the same width.

To align the different plots, you should keep them in the same `tikzpicture`, name the plots using `name`, and position them using `at=(<other plot name>.below south east), anchor=(north east)` or something similar. The anchors `south`, `south east`, etc. refer to points on the axes, the anchors `below south east`, `right of south east`, etc. refer to projections of points on the axes onto the bounding box of the plot.

[image: aligned plots]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/MyAxisStyle/.style={xmin=0,xmax=5, ymin=0,ymax=3,height=4cm,width=0.9\linewidth,scale only axis}}
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/MyLineStyle/.style={samples=50, smooth, ultra thick}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}\centering
\hrule% To see actual \linewidth
\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[MyAxisStyle, xmax=10, ymax=110,scale only axis,name=first]
    \addplot[MyLineStyle, domain=0:10, ,red] {(x^2)} node [left] {$y=x^2$};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[MyAxisStyle, xmax=2,ymax=9,
    at=(first.below south west),
    anchor=north west,
    yshift=-0.25cm,
    name=second]
    \addplot[MyLineStyle, domain=0:2 ,green] {(x)^3} node [left] {$y=x^3$};
\end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[MyAxisStyle,
    width=0.4\linewidth,
    at=(second.below south west),
    anchor=north west,
    yshift=-0.25cm,
    name=third]
    \addplot[MyLineStyle, domain=0:5, blue] {sqrt(x)} node [above left] {$y=\sqrt{x}$};
\end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[MyAxisStyle, height=3cm,width=0.4\linewidth,
    at=(second.east|-third.outer south east),
    anchor=outer south east
    ]
    \addplot[MyLineStyle, domain=0:5, blue] {sqrt(x)} node [above left] {$y=\sqrt{x}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hrule% To see actual \linewidth
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works well. I'd prefer to have separate `tikzpicture` environment, so is there a way to apply a format to the axis labels so that they are typeset within a given space so that they occupy the same width. I could manually do that but would prefer that the specific tick labels are automatically selected.

Comment: You could set `\pgfplotsset{yticklabel style={text width=3em,align=right}}` to make all y labels take up the same amount of horizontal space, which will make the graphs align correctly on the left hand side if you remove the `\centering` (if you keep things centered, you also need to set the `xticklabel style` to a common width because the labels protrude on the right hand side of the graphs). This won't help in aligning things on the right hand side, though.

Comment: I also prefer to use separate `tikzpicture` environments whenever I need more than one plot. Often, I excluded the axis descriptions from the bounding box using the trim features: this allows `\centering` if the left axis has its labels on its left and the right axis on its right - for all axes, independent of their label widths. The involved examples have made their way into the pgfplots manual, section "Alignment"...