pgfplots different axis scaling in one diagram for I-V-characteristics of a diode
I have a set of measurements for constructing the characteristic curve of a diode, and I would like to format my plot similar to the one shown below. However, I need to have the axes in different scales to accurately represent the data.
Could anyone guide me on how to achieve this in LaTeX? Specifically, I’m looking for advice on how to adjust the scales of the axes appropriately while ensuring that the overall layout remains clear. 
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{width=20cm,compat=1.18} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend pos = outer north east,
    axis lines = center,
    x label style = {anchor=north west},
    y label style = {anchor=south west},
    xtick = {-5.5,-5,-4.5,-4,-3.5,-3,-2.5,-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5},
    ytick = {-12,-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10,12},
    ymajorgrids = true,
    xmajorgrids = true,
    grid style = dashed
]


  
\addplot[color = red, mark=diamond*]
    coordinates {
    
       (0, 0)
        (0.613, 0.02)
        (0.722, 0.62)
        (0.743, 1.4)
        (0.757, 2.2)
        (0.764, 2.8)
        (0.768, 3.4)
        (0.773, 4)
        (0.779, 5)
        (0.783, 5.8)
        (0.788, 7)
    
    };


    
\addplot[color = blue, mark=square*]
    coordinates {
    
       (0, 0)
        (-0.624, 0)
        (-5.76, 0)
        (-6.07, 0.04)
        (-6.09, 0.09)
        (-6.11, 0.76)
        (-6.13, 0.90)
        (-6.14, 1.90)
        (-6.15, 3)
        (-6.17, 3.7)
        (-6.19, 4.4)
    
    };

      

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Thank you for your help!

Maybe you could try something llike unit vector ratio = 1 0.5 in the axis options? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39916/319072
