# How to shift yticklabels vertically?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, vertical-alignment, matrices

When plotting data matrices as done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126799/scale-axis-in-pgfplots-without-changing-orientation) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73640/using-pgfplots-how-do-i-arrange-my-data-matrix-for-a-surface-plot-so-that-each), the tick labels get drawn at the border of fields. They should be drawn in the center.
I've tried shifting them using `hspace` and `vspace`.
This works for the xticklabels, but not for the yticklabels.

It could be done manually by setting:
`yticks = {0.5}` and `yticklabels = {1}`, but this command is called for plots of different sizes.

This seems like there should be an easy solution, but I didn't find anything in the manual.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
        0 0 0.77
        0 1 0

        1 0 0
        1 1 0
}\data
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=5cm,
    %title={\texttt{Minimal purity plot}},
        colormap={bluenew}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,255,255); rgb255(1cm)=(40,40,240)},
        colorbar,
        colorbar style={
                at={(1.5, 0.5)},
                anchor=west,
                xticklabel pos=right,
                try min ticks=3,
        height=1.5cm,
        x=0.25cm
        },
        xticklabel = {\hspace{-1.5cm}$\pgfmathprintnumber\tick$},
        yticklabel = {\vspace{-1.5cm}$\pgfmathprintnumber\tick$},
        xtickmin = 1,
        ytickmin = 1,
        xtick=data,
        ytick=data,
        point meta min=0,
        point meta max=1,
        xlabel=original feature,
        ylabel=recovered feature,
        y label style = {rotate=90},
        axis equal,
        x = 1.5cm,
        y = 1.5cm,
        z = 0cm ]
\addplot3 [surf, shader=flat corner] table {\data};
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There was in fact an easy solution: The ticklabels can be shifted by using (surprise!) `xshift` and `yshift`. Somehow this eluded me during the first read of the manual.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
        0 0 0.77
        0 1 0

        1 0 0
        1 1 0
}\data
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=5cm,
    %title={\texttt{Minimal purity plot}},
        colormap={bluenew}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,255,255); rgb255(1cm)=(40,40,240)},
        colorbar,
        colorbar style={
                at={(1.5, 0.5)},
                anchor=west,
                xticklabel pos=right,
                try min ticks=3,
        height=1.5cm,
        x=0.25cm
        },
        xticklabel style = {xshift=-0.75cm},
        yticklabel = {yshift=-0.75cm},
        xtickmin = 1,
        ytickmin = 1,
        xtick=data,
        ytick=data,
        point meta min=0,
        point meta max=1,
        xlabel=original feature,
        ylabel=recovered feature,
        y label style = {rotate=90},
        axis equal,
        x = 1.5cm,
        y = 1.5cm,
        z = 0cm ]
\addplot3 [surf, shader=flat corner] table {\data};
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]