# Alignment of axis in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hello I have a Problem with the alignment of the y-axis in TikZ! The y-axis of the last plot isn't aligned to the other two plots! trim axis left doesn't work!
Can somebody help me? Thanks!

```
\documentclass[svgnames,a4paper,ngerman,fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=8,yscale=5]
\draw [->, thick] (0,0) -- (0,0.5)node[left]{$U,I$};
\draw [->, thick] (0,0) -- (1.1,0)node[below]{$t$}; 
\draw [blue, ultra thick, rounded corners] (0,0.3)--(0.1,0.3)--(0.15,0.22)--(0.2,0.22)--(0.22,0.02)--(0.8,0.02)--(0.85,0.4)--(0.88,0.3)--(1,0.3)node[above,blue]{$u(t)$};
\draw [red, ultra thick, rounded corners] (0,0)--(0.1,0)--(0.18,0.4)--(0.2,0.3)--(0.83,0.3)--(0.85,0.0)--(1,0.0)node[above,red]{$i(t)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=8,yscale=5]
\draw [->, thick] (0,0) -- (0,0.5)node[left]{$P$};
\draw [->, thick] (0,0) -- (1.1,0)node[below]{$t$}; 
\draw [orange, ultra thick, rounded corners] (0,0)--(0.1,0)--(0.15,0.4)--(0.22,0.05)--(0.8,0.05)--(0.85,0.3)--(0.9,0.0)--(1.0,0.0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=8,yscale=5]
\draw [->, thick] (0,0) -- (0,0.5)node[left]{$E$};
\draw [->, thick] (0,0) -- (1.1,0)node[below]{$t$}; 
\draw[purple, ultra thick, rounded corners]
(0,0)--(0.1,0)--(0.2,0.2)--(0.8,0.3)--(0.9,0.4)--(1,0.4);
\draw[thick](0.1,-0.01)--(0.1,0.01);
\draw[thick](0.2,-0.01)--(0.2,0.01);
\draw (0.15,0)node[below]{$E_{on}$};
\draw[thick](0.8,-0.01)--(0.8,0.01);
\draw[thick](0.9,-0.01)--(0.9,0.01);
\draw (0.85,0)node[below]{$E_{off}$};
\draw[decorate,thick,decoration={brace, mirror}] (0.2,-0.01)--node[below]{xxx}(0.8,-0.01) ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Plot}\label{fig:PvIGBT}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `trim axis left` only works if you use PGFPlots and its `axis` environment. Could you turn your code snippet into a complete compilable minimal example document (starting from `\documentclass`)?

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The misalignment is caused by the labels below the x-axis, which causes the last figure to have a bigger bounding box than the two first ones.

You can manually specify the bounding box of each figure, giving the same bounding box to the three, using as the dimensions of the bb those of the axis. This means to add to each tikzpicture the following line:

```
\path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (1.1, 0.5);
```

The result:

[image: Result]

Note however that, everything which is outside of the bounding box is "not part of the figure", although it is shown nevertheless, so it can overlap the surrounding text. In this case this effect is almost unnoticeable (the caption of the figure will be a little closer to the x-axis of the plots).

Answer (score 3):

If you were using `pgfplot` the usual thing would be to adjust the style for the labels as in:

- [Aligning subplots in a pgfplots figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36442/aligning-subplots-in-a-pgfplots-figure), and
- [PGFplot to occupy full \linewidth, and aligned y=axis across tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24855/pgfplot-to-occupy-full-linewidth-and-aligned-y-axis-across-tikzpicture)

Since you are using `tikz` the above solutions won't work in this specific case, however you can emulate that using a `\makebox[][]{}` to ensure that the labels all occupy the same amount of space. So, below I have defined a `\FormatLabel` macro that ensures that the labels all occupy `3em` of horizontal space:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[svgnames,a4paper,ngerman,fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Equivalent of the following \pgfplotsset set is \FormatLabel
%\pgfplotsset{yticklabel style={text width=3em,align=right}}
\newcommand*{\FormatLabel}[1]{\makebox[3em][r]{#1}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=8,yscale=5]
\draw [->, thick] (0,0) -- (0,0.5)node[left]{\FormatLabel{$U,I$}};
\draw [->, thick] (0,0) -- (1.1,0)node[below]{$t$}; 
\draw [blue, ultra thick, rounded corners] (0,0.3)--(0.1,0.3)--(0.15,0.22)--(0.2,0.22)--(0.22,0.02)--(0.8,0.02)--(0.85,0.4)--(0.88,0.3)--(1,0.3)node[above,blue]{$u(t)$};
\draw [red, ultra thick, rounded corners] (0,0)--(0.1,0)--(0.18,0.4)--(0.2,0.3)--(0.83,0.3)--(0.85,0.0)--(1,0.0)node[above,red]{$i(t)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=8,yscale=5]
\draw [->, thick] (0,0) -- (0,0.5)node[left]{\FormatLabel{$P$}};
\draw [->, thick] (0,0) -- (1.1,0)node[below]{$t$}; 
\draw [orange, ultra thick, rounded corners] (0,0)--(0.1,0)--(0.15,0.4)--(0.22,0.05)--(0.8,0.05)--(0.85,0.3)--(0.9,0.0)--(1.0,0.0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=8,yscale=5]
\draw [->, thick] (0,0) -- (0,0.5)node[left]{\FormatLabel{$E$}};
\draw [->, thick] (0,0) -- (1.1,0)node[below]{$t$}; 
\draw[purple, ultra thick, rounded corners]
(0,0)--(0.1,0)--(0.2,0.2)--(0.8,0.3)--(0.9,0.4)--(1,0.4);
\draw[thick](0.1,-0.01)--(0.1,0.01);
\draw[thick](0.2,-0.01)--(0.2,0.01);
\draw (0.15,0)node[below]{$E_{on}$};
\draw[thick](0.8,-0.01)--(0.8,0.01);
\draw[thick](0.9,-0.01)--(0.9,0.01);
\draw (0.85,0)node[below]{$E_{off}$};
\draw[decorate,thick,decoration={brace, mirror}] (0.2,-0.01)--node[below]{xxx}(0.8,-0.01) ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Plot}\label{fig:PvIGBT}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```