# Using pgfplots, add vertical/horizontal spacing between plots?

Tags: pgfplots

I once already asked a very similar question; [How can I add space between two separate plots, using pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71583/how-can-i-add-space-between-two-separate-plots-using-pgfplots). But this is some what different.

I have the following code;

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=0.0004, ymax=0.0012,
ylabel={$\phi_{\mathrm{i}}(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids,
name=plot1]

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=0.2, ymax=1.2,
ylabel={$h(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids,
name=plot2,
at=(plot1.right of north east), anchor=left of north west]

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=0.0004, ymax=0.0012,
ylabel={$\phi_{\mathrm{o}}(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids,
name=plot4,
at=(plot1.below south west), anchor=above north west]

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=2000, ymax=12000,
ylabel={$p_{\mathrm{i}}(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids,
name=plot5,
at=(plot4.right of north east), anchor=left of north west]

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This creates the following plot:

[image: Without any spacing using x- yshift.]

I think there is to few vertical/horizontal spacing between the plots. I want to increase this. Currently I use x- yshift, this gives the following result:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=0.0004, ymax=0.0012,
ylabel={$\phi_{\mathrm{i}}(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids,
name=plot1]

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
xshift=1cm,
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=0.2, ymax=1.2,
ylabel={$h(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids,
name=plot2,
at=(plot1.right of north east), anchor=left of north west]

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
yshift=-1cm,
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=0.0004, ymax=0.0012,
ylabel={$\phi_{\mathrm{o}}(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids,
name=plot4,
at=(plot1.below south west), anchor=above north west]

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
xshift=1cm,
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=2000, ymax=12000,
ylabel={$p_{\mathrm{i}}(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids,
name=plot5,
at=(plot4.right of north east), anchor=left of north west]

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: With spacing using x- yshift]

I want to know if there is a more consistent manner to do this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You might want to have a look to the `groupplots` library (see the documentation **5.5 Grouping plots**).

It allows you to deploy graphs in a grid by selecting the `group size` (e.g. `group size= 2 by 2` for your case) or directly the number of `rows` and `columns`. Then you can customize the horizontal and vertical distance among the graphs by means of the keys `horizontal sep` and `vertical sep`.

In your case, a possible solution is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2, horizontal sep=2cm, vertical sep=2cm}]

\nextgroupplot[%
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=0.0004, ymax=0.0012,
ylabel={$\phi_{\mathrm{i}}(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids]
\addplot coordinates{(0,0.0005)(15000,0.001)};

\nextgroupplot[%
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=0.2, ymax=1.2,
ylabel={$h(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids]
\addplot coordinates{(0,0.5)(15000,1)};

\nextgroupplot[%
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=0.0004, ymax=0.0012,
ylabel={$\phi_{\mathrm{o}}(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids]
\addplot coordinates{(1000,0.0004)(15000,0.001)};

\nextgroupplot[%
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=2000, ymax=12000,
ylabel={$p_{\mathrm{i}}(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids]
\addplot coordinates{(5000,2010)(19000,11500)};

\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I however do not want to use groupplot. The problem lays in when I want to plot a uneven number of plots. You then get, for example, 3 plots on the first row and 2 on the second row in matrix style. The problem is that this is ugly, I want the 2 plots on the second row at that moment centered compared to the first row.

Comment: @WG- You can use two sets of groupplots and place them relatively.

Comment: I haven't thought of that. But it's a lot of work for something this small. I hope a future release of pgfplots maybe can do this all automatic. I.e. in the groupplot you can set the space distance (already available) but when you make a groupplot of 2x3 and leave one entry open that that it centers automatically. For now I think I will stick with my own solution and just use `xshift` and `yshift`.

Comment: `horizontal sep` applies to all plots in the `groupplots`. Can you set different distances between individual plots? Say, if you have 3 plots in a row, then set 3cm and 5cm distance between 1-2 and 2-3 plots, respectively.

Answer (score 9):

Since matrix alignment is unsuitable, you can still rely on standard LaTeX box alignment combined with `\centering`. That would automatically align your images - and it would automatically ensure that the last line is centered independently.

In fact, this is considerably simpler in terms of writing and maintenance of the code, and it also produces individual, independent images (which is something that I always like compared to a single, huge, involved picture).

Here is what I think about, applied to your example (see below for explanation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\centering

\tikzset{trim axis left,trim axis right}
\def\distance{2cm}%

\dotfill
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=0.0004, ymax=0.0012,
ylabel={$\phi_{\mathrm{i}}(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids,
name=plot1]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hspace{\distance}%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=0.0004, ymax=0.0012,
ylabel={$\phi_{\mathrm{i}}(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids,
name=plot1]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hspace{\distance}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=0.2, ymax=1.2,
ylabel={$h(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids,
name=plot2,
]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\dotfill
\vspace{1.2cm}%

\dotfill
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=0.0004, ymax=0.0012,
ylabel={$\phi_{\mathrm{o}}(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids,
name=plot4,
]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hspace{\distance}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=3cm,
height=3cm,
scale only axis,
every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
xlabel={$t$},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
ymin=2000, ymax=12000,
ylabel={$p_{\mathrm{i}}(t)$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids,
name=plot5,
]

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}%
\dotfill

\end{document}
```

[image]

The key idea is to generate five individual pictures. The first three pictures are separated by `\hspace{\distance}` which produces the desired distance. You see that I defined `\distance` to be `2cm`.

Then, the line is terminated using a new paragraph. The second line contains two pictures which are separated by `\hspace{\distance}` as well. In addition, the vertical distance is defined by a `\vspace`.

Since the complete stuff has been typeset after `\centering`, the lines will be centered individually (in fact, the `\centering` is redundant in my example because of the `\dotfill`s. But I suppose that you will remove them anyway, see below).

There is one challenge in the alignment: it can easily happen that axis descriptions have different sizes. However, the eye always gets caught by the axis box - so we should align on the axis box, even if the tick labels or axis labels would result in a different alignment. Consequently, I wrote the line

```
\tikzset{trim axis left,trim axis right}
```

which applies to *all* following pictures (until the next closing brace or `\end{...}`). This statement causes TikZ to exclude everything left of the axis and everything right of the axis. This *requires* manual control over the spacing. Furthermore, it can lead to axis descriptions in the side's margin. But I believe that it is still a tremendiously useful feature. The `\dotfill`s show the result: they indicate the end of the bounding boxes on the left and on the right. You can remove them, they are just for the purpose of illustration.

Note that you could write a `\pgfplotsset{<common options>}` in front of your pictures (or using a common style key). These options will apply to all following pictures until the next closing curly brace or `\end{...}`.

Personally, I find this kind of alignment quite appealing because you can easily copy-paste individual pictures to other documents (well, together with the shared set of options) and because it lets LaTeX do the alignment job. The same approach could be combined with standard LaTeX `tabular`s - just in the same way as for `\includegraphics`, except that the `trim left, trim right` allows a powerful difference.

Ah - you may want to add `baseline` to the first `\tikzset`. It will automatically control the *vertical* alignment of adjacent pictures.

Comment: How can I use your code using the standalone package? When I use your code the plots are all plotted on the same line. Using the 'varwidth' option of the standalone package did not help either.

Comment: @WG- Start the file via `\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}` instead.