# Align plots in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, subcaption

Can somebody help me? I try to align two plots horizontally in pgfplots!
In the preamble I have:

**MWE***

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,subcaption}
\pgfplotsset{ compat=1.7,
dacrip plot/.style={ % Set common styles that can be applied to the axis environment
    x=2cm, y=2cm,                   % Unit vector length
    axis lines=middle,              % Axis lines go through (0,0)
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,     % No tick marks
    ymin=0, ymax=1.75,              % Y axis range
    enlargelimits=upper,            % Increase upper range a bit
    clip=false,                     % Allow labels to extend beyond the axis
    disabledatascaling,             % Allow to draw TikZ objects without having to use (axis cs:<x>,<y>)
    x label style={anchor=north},   % Alignment of axis labels
    y label style={anchor=east},
    yticklabel style={align=right}
}
}    
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth} \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[dacrip plot, xlabel=$f$, ylabel=$U$]
       \addplot [blue, ultra thick] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,1) };
        \draw [dashed] (0,1) -- (1,1) node [pos=0, anchor=east] {$U_{max}$};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{Plot 1}\label{fig:ufMna}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth} \centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[dacrip plot, xlabel=$n$, ylabel=$M$ ]
       \addplot [blue, ultra thick] coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)} parabola [bend at end] (2,0.3);
   \end{axis};

\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{Plot 2}\label{fig:ufMnb}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{2 Plots}
\label{fig:ufMn}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

The problem is that the x-axis of Plot 2 is to short. Another problem is that the alignment of the x-axis is there, but the captions of the two plots aren't aligned!

---

***** Modified from OP's snippet

Comment: You might find useful the `groupplots` library: see as reference [How to align PGFplot subplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99181/how-to-align-pgfplot-subplots) and [Using pgfplots, add vertical/horizontal spacing between plots?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86995/using-pgfplots-add-vertical-horizontal-spacing-between-plots)

Comment: Could you turn the code snippet into a complete compilable document (starting from `\documentclass`)?

Answer (score 6):

<strike>I cannot compile all your stuff, because of missing headers, but this should align the caption:</strike>

Adding a `\vphantom{f]` in your xlabel will add the missing vertical space to align the subcaptions:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,subcaption}
\pgfplotsset{ compat=1.7,
dacrip plot/.style={ % Set common styles that can be applied to the axis environment
    x=2cm, y=2cm,                   % Unit vector length
    axis lines=middle,              % Axis lines go through (0,0)
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,     % No tick marks
    ymin=0, ymax=1.75,              % Y axis range
    enlargelimits=upper,            % Increase upper range a bit
    clip=false,                     % Allow labels to extend beyond the axis
    disabledatascaling,             % Allow to draw TikZ objects without having to use (axis cs:<x>,<y>)
    x label style={anchor=north},   % Alignment of axis labels
    y label style={anchor=east},
    yticklabel style={align=right}
}
}    
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth} \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[dacrip plot, xlabel=$f$, ylabel=$U$]
       \addplot [blue, ultra thick] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,1) };
        \draw [dashed] (0,1) -- (1,1) node [pos=0, anchor=east] {$U_{max}$};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{Plot 1}\label{fig:ufMna}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth} \centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[dacrip plot, xlabel={$n$\vphantom{f}}, ylabel=$M$ , xmax=2]
       \addplot [blue, ultra thick] coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)} parabola [bend at end] (2,0.3);
   \end{axis};

\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{Plot 2}\label{fig:ufMnb}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{2 Plots}
\label{fig:ufMn}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I think that TeX will use the bounding box to position picture and caption, but in your case, your 2 pictures do not have the same size (here depth). Adding a `\vphantom` in the xlabel should add the required space to align the bottom of each graph.

**Edit:** for the second question, you could manually adjust the x-axis via the `xmax` key.

[image: output]

Comment: Genius! Your \vphantom trick works, but you have forgotten the $$ signs around the f!

Comment: Are there any suggestions for the problem with the x-axis in plot 2 ?

Comment: You don't need $$ around the f, as all letter with "depth" have the same depth; using g or p instead f work also well

Comment: I have updated my answer for your second question

Comment: $U_{max}$ should be $U_{\max}$