# Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/horizontal sep' with groupplot using pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I am trying to draw multiple plots with `groupplot` and am getting the errors below.

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/horizontal sep', to which you passed '20pt', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ]
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/vertical sep', to which you passed '20pt', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ]
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/x unit', to which you passed '\si {\byte }', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ]
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/y unit', to which yout. ]
```

The offending code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage[binary-units = true]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}
            [
            group style={group size=2 by 1},
            horizontal sep=20pt,
            vertical sep=20pt,
            width=0.5\columnwidth,
            every x tick scale label/.style={at={(rel axis cs:1,0)},yshift=-1.5em,anchor=north east,inner sep=1pt},
            every y tick scale label/.style={at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},xshift=-1.75em,anchor=south east,inner sep=1pt},
            xmin = 0,
            ymin = 0,
            grid=major,
            grid style={dashed,gray!30},
            xlabel=X Axis $\mathcal{N}$,
            ylabel=Y Axis $Time$,
            x unit=\si{\byte},
            y unit=\si{\second},
            legend cell align={left},
            legend style={at={(0.5,-0.4)},anchor=north}
            ]
            
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot[color=teal,only marks]
            table[x=Message Length,y=Insertion Time,col sep=comma,scatter] {data.csv};
            \addlegendentry{Insertion}
            \addplot [mark=none,color=Aquamarine2]
            table[x=Message Length,y={create col/linear regression={y=Insertion Time}},col sep=comma] {data.csv};
            \addlegendentry{Insertion Regression Line}
            
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot[mark=none,color=Cyan4,thick]
            table[x=Message Length,y={create col/linear regression={y=Extraction Time}},col sep=comma] {data.csv};
            \addlegendentry{Extraction Regression Line}
    \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

I am in pursuit to prevent the `ylabel` from overlapping for the plot for which I have resorted to using `horizontal sep=5cm` as provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86998) and [in the documentation](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Esimardr/pgfplots.pdf#pgfp./pgfplots/group/horizontal%3Asep). The error is what I assume is preventing the solution from working as intended. Any guidance is appretiated.

Sample from `data.csv`:

```
Message Length,Insertion Time,Extraction Time
1000000,2882.6947407000002,2891.3703151000004
2000000,5969.4817235,5931.724818600001
3000000,8480.4446118,8307.060654199999
4000000,11374.857455500001,10956.432963199999
5000000,13943.201667899999,13806.727052399998
6000000,16637.710391300003,16383.8475286
7000000,19527.7743606,19134.5409173
8000000,22427.304584700003,21726.507952400003
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did only two minor mistakes which lead to the error messages. Have a look at the comments in the code how to fix them. I also gave two hints how to prevent "the overlapping".

(Please note that I have heavily simplified your code to show only relevant stuff.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{
        groupplots,
        % missed to load the library to make `x unit` and friend work
        units,
    }
    % (add this to `compat` level or higher to make use of the advanced positioning
    % of the axis labels)
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\usepackage[binary-units=true]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group size=2 by 1,
            % moved the next two to this style
            horizontal sep=40pt,    % (<-- increased value to prevent overlapping)
            vertical sep=20pt,
        },
        x unit=\si{\byte},
        y unit=\si{\second},
    ]

    \nextgroupplot
        \addplot {x};

    \nextgroupplot
        \addplot {x^2};
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]