# How to make wide plot without impacting all the labels?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams

So far I've tried resizebox and tikzpicture xscale/yscale. They stretch all the labels (including the title) and make them look very ugly. Is there any way to avoid it?

Above is what I get, below is what I want (made in Maple):
[image]
Code sample:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=0.1in]{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{every axis x label/.append style={font=\tiny, yshift=0.8em}, every axis y label/.append style={font=\tiny, yshift=-2em}, every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny}}
\begin{document}
\newpage

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=2.5, xscale = 3.5]
\begin{axis}[xlabel={t (fs)},
ylabel={C (eV)},
xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25},
enlargelimits = false,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=solid,
title = {C(t)}]
\addplot[color=red, mark=none]
coordinates {
(0,80)
(1,0)
(2,-10)
(3,0)
(4,60)
(5,70)
(6,60)
(7,0)
(8,-10)
(9,0)
(10,50)
(11,60)
(12,50)
(13,0)
(14,-10)
(15,0)
(16,40)
(17,50)
(18,40)
(19,0)
(20,-10)
(21,0)
(22,30)
(23,40)
(24,30)
(25,0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. One question per post, please.

Comment: You can use `smooth`: `\addplot[color=red, mark=none,smooth]` and `\begin{axis}[ymin = 0, ymax = 5, xmin = 0, xmax = 5`.

Comment: Limits: `xmax=`, `ymax=`.

Comment: Thanks, I 've already removed both little questions, since they are answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24864/124577) you could simply use `scale only axis` to resize the whole graph, but not to scale labels.

Two: A smooth plot is achieved by using the option `smooth`. And to have limits you can use `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax`.

[image: scaling]

Code (I removed the `\tiny` to make the effect really visible):

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=0.1in]{geometry}
%\pgfplotsset{every axis x label/.append style={font=\tiny, yshift=0.8em}, every axis y label/.append style={font=\tiny, yshift=-2em}, every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny}}
\begin{document}
\newpage

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}%[yscale=2.5, xscale = 3.5]
\begin{axis}[height=.7\paperheight,width=.6\linewidth,scale only axis,xlabel={t (fs)},
ylabel={C (eV)},
xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25},
enlargelimits = false,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=solid,
title = {C(t)}]
\addplot[color=red, mark=none,smooth]
coordinates {
(0,80)
(1,0)
(2,-10)
(3,0)
(4,60)
(5,70)
(6,60)
(7,0)
(8,-10)
(9,0)
(10,50)
(11,60)
(12,50)
(13,0)
(14,-10)
(15,0)
(16,40)
(17,50)
(18,40)
(19,0)
(20,-10)
(21,0)
(22,30)
(23,40)
(24,30)
(25,0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @SigmundFreud If it solved your problem consider accepting the answer (green button).