# Scale tikz figure to a percentage of \textwidth

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, margins, scaling

A user [asked a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/scale-figure-to-a-percentage-of-textwidth) about scaling a figure to a factor of `\textwidth` and got an answer like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{file}
\end{document}
```

however, I'm not sure how to apply this to my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      %
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{This figure has a width which is a factor of \\textwidt}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I've tried

```
\begin{figure}[!h, width=\textwidth]
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: That solution would work if you produce a single file containing the image produced by the `tikz`.

Comment: @sigur yes but I have dozens of tikz figures and I don't want the source for my document to be spread across dozens of files that I need to keep, backup, and maintain constantly. There must be a way to scale it. `\resizebox[\textwidt][!]{...}` doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: In this case you have to scale the `tikz` using `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]` for example. But this will change the scale of coordinates.

Comment: `\resizebox` works. You should use it as follows: `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}}`

Comment: The answers to this question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17293/18228, may be helpful.

Comment: `\resizebox[\textwidt][!]{...}` will scale fonts too.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need [`tikzscale`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzscale) package. Save the contents

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
  \node at (0,0) {Me};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

as `myfig.tikz` (say) and use `\includegraphics`

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{filecontents}    %% only for this demo
\begin{filecontents*}{myfig.tikz}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
      \node at (0,0) {Me};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{myfig.tikz}
    \caption{This figure has a width which is a factor of text width}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{myfig.tikz}
    \caption{This figure has a width which is a factor of text width}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unlike `\resizebox`, the fonts are not scaled in-appropriately. If you want to scale fonts too, use `\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]` instead of `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

With `\resizebox` from `graphicx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
      \node at (0,0) {Me};
  \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
    \caption{This figure has a width which is a factor of text width}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.2\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
      \node at (0,0) {Me};
  \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
    \caption{This figure has a width which is a factor of text width}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If the fonts are not scaled, then unfortunately I cannot use this method.

Comment: @user41709 Scaling fonts is a bad idea. Any way it is your document. You can use `\resizebox` then.

Comment: @user41709: You can still use this method, I think, if you pass the `transform shape` option to `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @HarishKumar The issue is I've spent weeks on all the content and figures for one document, and now for a different conference we need to use a template with a significantly narrower text width. I simply do not have the time to re-create these figures for the larger page margins.

Comment: So my best option is to compile each figure as a separate PDF file, and include them with a scale? That will scale everything correctly?

Answer (score 8):

You may want to consider package `adjustbox` as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (10,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{This figure uses no factor}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (10,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{This figure uses 0.5 factor}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.7\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (10,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{This figure uses factor 0.7}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]