# Why does \resizebox around tikzpicture gives me undefined control sequence }?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

As indicated in [Scale tikz figure to a percentage of \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155314/scale-tikz-figure-to-a-percentage-of-textwidth) I was expecting this to work:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix(Person) [matrix of nodes, 
                 matrix/.style={rows={1}{fill=gray}},
                 label=above:Person, 
                 column 1/.style={nodes={text width=1cm, align=center}},
                 column 2/.style={nodes={text width=2cm}},
                 column 3/.style={nodes={text width=2.5cm}},
                 column 4/.style={nodes={text width=2cm}},
                 column 5/.style={nodes={text width=2cm, align=center}}
                  ] {
    id & name       & address       & birth date & occupation.id \\
    1  & Mary Smith & Main street 1 & 1970-04-17 & 1 \\
    2  & John Doe   & Highway 2     & 1972-07-24 & 1 \\ 
    3  & Clara Doe  & Highway 2     & 1995-11-11 & 2 \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, it gives me:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options 

l.24 }

?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It shouldn't give that error; if you remove the blank line before `\matrix` you get the more informative `! Package pgf Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.` Look for `ampersand replacement` in the manual.

Comment: @egreg I am not able to reproduce that :(

Comment: @egreg, oh, btw, which manual would that be? Some of the various TeX manuals?

Comment: @jonalv `pgf` manual. Section 20.5 of the current version. But I am not able to generate the error message noted by egreg either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `&` inside the matrix, which are handled in a non-standard way by tikz and cause problems when used as argument in other commands.

The solution is to replace each `&` by `\&` and to put `ampersand replacement=\&` in matrix options, as in the following code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix(Person) [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&,
                 matrix/.style={rows={1}{fill=gray}},
                 label=above:Person, 
                 column 1/.style={nodes={text width=1cm, align=center}},
                 column 2/.style={nodes={text width=2cm}},
                 column 3/.style={nodes={text width=2.5cm}},
                 column 4/.style={nodes={text width=2cm}},
                 column 5/.style={nodes={text width=2cm, align=center}}
                  ] {
    id \& name       \& address       \& birth date \& occupation.id \\
    1  \& Mary Smith \& Main street 1 \& 1970-04-17 \& 1 \\
    2  \& John Doe   \& Highway 2     \& 1972-07-24 \& 1 \\ 
    3  \& Clara Doe  \& Highway 2     \& 1995-11-11 \& 2 \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]