# How to make Tikz image move to left of the page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I use Tikz to draw a image, but the image is little big and too right in the page, i want the image move to left in the page, how to do it? 
I tried to smallize the font size, but this does not make it move to left

Comment: You can use `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=<amount>]`. `<amount>` is a number like 0.8. Or you can use `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{your tikzpicture}`

Comment: Also add `\noindent` before the `tikzpicture` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short sum up of this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155314/scale-tikz-figure-to-a-percentage-of-textwidth). It gives you the possibility to handle your `tikzpicture` like an image in a `figure`-environment. This way you can set the width of your `tikzpicture` to `<factor>\textwidth`.

This way you don't need to overlap your graphic over the text's width.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{filecontents}{image.tikz}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (15,5) node [midway] {Slightly too big rectangle};;
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image.tikz}
 \caption{tikz in figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered image]

Comment: You could also use a \savebox.