# Tikzpicture also scaling "dashed", "dotted", etc., patterns

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, pattern

I was wondering why predefined patterns like dashed, dotted, thick, etc., 
do not scaled when scaling the complete tikzpicture environment.

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape, scale=.3]
            \draw[very thick, dashed] (0,0) -- (10, 0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[very thick, dashed] (0,0) -- (10, 0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Also related. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scale` parameter only scales the coordinates. In order to scale the whole environment you have to use `scalebox` or `resizeobox`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \scalebox{0.3}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
            \draw[very thick, dashed] (0,0) -- (10, 0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[very thick, dashed] (0,0) -- (10, 0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```