# Scaling tikz graph when pgfplots is loaded

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikzscale

This question is related to:

---

[tikz: Scaling the unscalable — issues with a TikZ graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249779/tikz-scaling-the-unscalable-issues-with-a-tikz-graph/249792#249792)

---

I'm using the suggested modification from the linked answer to scale tikz graphs. However, I'm also including plots created with `pgfplots`. Adding `\usepackage{pgfplots}` to the given example produces the following error when including the second graph:

```
Undefined control sequence. \ScaleFactor ->\tikzscale@scale
```

Here's the modified MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\let\OrgPgfTransformScale\pgftransformscale
\renewcommand*{\pgftransformscale}[1]{%
  \gdef\ScaleFactor{#1}%
  \OrgPgfTransformScale{#1}%
}
\def\ScaleFactor{1}


\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=3cm*\ScaleFactor,
  main node/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
  }
]
    \typeout{* Scale factor: \ScaleFactor}

    % nodes
    \node[main node] (A)  {A};
    \node[main node] (B) [right of=A] {B};

    % lines
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\large}]
       (A) edge [bend right] node[below] {0.0} (B)
       (B) edge [bend right] node [below] {0.0} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{figure} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test.tikz}
    \caption{This figure has standard width}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{test.tikz}
    \caption{This figure has half width}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to use this `\ScaleFactor` mechanism for multiple graphs while using `pgfplots` at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx), replace `\gdef\ScaleFactor` by  `\xdef\ScaleFactor`.

Comment: Did the trick of Salim help you or do you need further assistance?