# How to Arrange Graphics (TikZ) If Using Input Command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, input

I am trying to arrange several figures e.g. as follows:

[image]

Those are `.tikz` files, and I am using `\input` to insert them.

What I am trying right now is this:

```latex
\begin{figure}[p]
        \centering  
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
        \centering
        \input{Figures/Versuche/Temperatur_Messprogramm_Messreihe_1.tikz}
        \caption{Temperatur Messprogramm Messreihe 1}
        \label{Temperatur_Messprogramm_Messreihe_1}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
        \centering
        \input{Figures/Versuche/Temperatur_Messprogramm_Messreihe_2.tikz}
        \caption{Temperatur Messprogramm Messreihe 2}
        \label{Temperatur_Messprogramm_Messreihe_2}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{1.00\linewidth}
        \centering
        \input{Figures/Versuche/Temperatur_Messprogramm_Messreihe_3.tikz}
        \caption{Temperatur Messprogramm Messreihe 3}
        \label{Temperatur_Messprogramm_Messreihe_3}
    \end{minipage}
\label{Temperaturmessprogramm}
\end{figure}
```

This seems to work it would be  `\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]` instead of `\input`. `\input` however does not accept the `[width=1.0\linewidth]` bit.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: You could have a look at the `tikzscale` package: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155314/scale-tikz-figure-to-a-percentage-of-textwidth/155317#155317

Comment: How can I do `\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{smallfigure2}` for `\input`? Basically an `\input[width=3cm,height=2cm]{smallfigure2}`.

Comment: See the link in my comment. (I copied the wrong link first, sorry, so I edited the comment.) `\input` just inserts the text in the specified file, but with `tikzscale` you can use `\includegraphics` with `.tikz` files.

Comment: As a last measure you can use `\resizebox`, also demonstrated in the answer I linked to. That will also change the size of the text, so in general I'd avoid it.

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much! This text does rescale though. This might be because the `.tikz` has been created by `matlab2tikz` automatically.

Comment: You can set the (approximate) width when you run matlab2tikz, then you don't have to scale later.

Comment: `\input` is just the same as copying the contents of the file at that point it does not create a tex box that can be scaled or have any properties at all

Comment: Just did a quick test: seems you need to remove any scaling options from the `axis` options. I.e. in `smallfigure2.tikz`, remove all of `scale only axis, width=<length>, height=<length>, axis equal` if present.