# Combine tikzscale and externalize with named external pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external, tikzscale

I have the same issue which has been discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29142/automagically-scale-tikz-picture-and-use-externalization) while trying to scale plots created using PGFplots. The issue is only present if I **name** the external pictures using `\tikzsetnextfilename`. However, naming them would be very helpful, otherwise all external images would be recreated if I added or removed one of them (right?).

The OP used a custom made script to scale the tikz picture, while I use the `tikzscale` package. In the manual, it says the `external` library is supported, but after compilation, the picture is printed unscaled.

Can someone confirm, that this is supposed to be working "out of the box", or do I have to tweak anything?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{bla.tikz}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{pic}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}


    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, axisratio=2]{bla}

\end{document}
```

[image]