# Automagically scale Tikz-Picture and use Externalization and setting of file name

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, tikz-external

I am trying to implement the solution to a question: [Automagically scale Tikz-Picture AND use Externalization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29142/221484)

The answer helps and I managed to do this, however I would like to give each externalized output image a specific file name, e.g. if my tikz file is at `path/to/file.tikz` then I would like to have the output file at `/ext-tikz/path/to/file.pdf`.

However, as soon as I implement `\tikzsetnextfilename{...}` the build fails.

Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}%
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
% 
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29145/221484
\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\def\tikzwidth{\textwidth}
\def\tikzheight{\textheight}
\newsavebox{\measure@tikzpicture}
\NewEnviron{tikzsize}[2]{%
\def\tikzscale{1}%
\tikzifexternalizingnext{%
    \def\tikz@width{#1}%
    \def\tikz@height{#2}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\measure@tikzpicture}%
    \tikzset{external/export next=false,external/optimize=false}% force translation of this BODY (and do not optimize it away as it would usually do):
    \BODY
    \end{lrbox}%
    \pgfmathparse{#1/\wd\measure@tikzpicture}%
    \edef\tikzscalewidth{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{#2/\ht\measure@tikzpicture}%
    \edef\tikzscaleheight{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{min(\tikzscalewidth, \tikzscaleheight)}%
    \edef\tikzscale{\pgfmathresult}%
    \BODY
}{% this will re-use an existing external graphics:
    \BODY
}
}
\makeatother
% 
%  
\begin{document}
% 
% \tikzsetnextfilename{output} %<-- if activated it fail's
% 
\begin{tikzsize}{\tikzwidth}{\tikzheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\tikzscale]
\draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzsize}
% 
\end{document}
```

I noteced inside the log files, that with the activated `tikzsetnextfilename` it says

> A tikzpicture has been optimized away. Use '/tikz/external/optimize=false' to disable this.

However when I use this feature, the generated image is not scaled anymore.

Comment: What do you want? Just auto-scale the tikz picture?

Comment: My goal is to scale images automatically, but also to have tikz externalized pdf files with the same name. Eventually, I want to use this to upload the resulting pdf files to a ShareLatex server, so that there the tikz images can be included via `includegraphics` if a *.pdf version of the file exists. I have a lot of tikz images for my dissertation. With ShareLatex I regularly run in a timeout (also for a single chapter).

Comment: As for my last comment. I wrote a shell script that looks into the log files of any externalized tikz output and gets the corresponding contained `*.tikz` file name from there. Then I simply change the filename so that it is easy to copy the `*.pdf` files into Sharelatex. But I would like to know if I am doing something wrong with my upper approach, in this case I want to learn from my mistakes, or maybe it is a bug, in this case I want to help others.