# TikZ datavisualization or pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-datavisualization

I want to create a few plots that should have the same style as my main document and it seems `tikz` is more than capable of achieving that.

Now while browsing the current `tikz` documentation (2.10 CVS) I found a long new section about data visualization. On the other hand there is the extra package `pgfplots` which seems at a first glance very similar but contains more plot types.

So what is recommend? What are the differences between the two approaches?

Comment: `pgfplots` is based on `tikz`, and would be recommended by a lot of folks for data visualization and plotting functions; have a look at [generating-dozens-of-graphs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60392/generating-dozens-of-graphs) for examples of how to style

Comment: The _long new section about data visualization_ in pgfmanual v2.10 **CVS** is **experimental**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "*long new section about data visualization*" in pgfmanual v2.10 **CVS** is **experimental**.

So, as this new version of TikZ is not released, it is recommended to use pgfplots.