# TikZ/PGF 3.0 datavisualization vs pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-datavisualization

To follow-up on a previous question [TikZ datavisualization or pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66264/tikz-datavisualization-or-pgfplots), the current release of
TikZ 3.0 has a flexible datavisualization engine that creates the same kind of plots as the more mature plotting package pgfplots.

What is the current recommendation for producing complete plots in LaTeX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer:

As of `pgf` v3.0, the `datavis` library is released to CTAN (no longer CVS-only). So the objective answer is *"use whichever you prefer"*. You will likely find proponents on both sides of the fence. But there is a greater user/community support base for `pgfplots` because, as you note, it is more mature at this point.

I personally prefer `pgfplots`, because `datavis` currently feels too verbose/pedantic for my taste. I'd rather have the `pgfplots` approach of "there are defaults here; customize them if/when needed". But again, this part is opinion-based. My opinion may change over time, and others have different opinions of course.

With a bit of time invested in learning, you can produce beautiful plots with either system. Happy TeXing/plotting! `:-)`

Comment: Does `pedantic/verbose` also imply that it enables users to make  more customization?

Comment: @Dilawar, I think not, as far as I could see from the Manual `datavisualization` and PGFplots offer different plots when no customization keys are used but you could customize one to look like the other or the other to look like the one. I think what Paul meant was that in `datavis` the keys are more verbal, just that.

Comment: Has your opinion changed now that almost 3 years have passed since you wrote this answer? Would you consider the built-in data visualization library to be sufficiently mature now? How do the user/community support bases of the two alternatives compare nowadays? Have your personal preferences changed?

Comment: Also: what would you recommend to a contemporary person who has not yet learned either of these alternatives, and who can only afford time to learn one of them?