# Using only a range of a csv file in TikZ using \datavisualization

Tags: tikz-pgf, csv, tikz-datavisualization

I would like to create a data visualization in TikZ. I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\begin{filecontents}{test.csv}
x y
-3 5
-2 7
-1 2
0 5
1 4
2 8
3 3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization
[
scientific axes,
all axes={length=5cm},
x axis={label=x, attribute=x, min value=-2, max value=2},
y axis={label=y, attribute=y, min value=0, max value=10},
visualize as line,
]
data[read from file=test.csv, separator={\space}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve that only a range ([-2, 2] in this case) of the csv file is used? It causes drawing errors, and loading unnecessary lines is time consuming when using large csv files.

[image: Drawing errors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{test.csv}
x y
-3 5
-2 7
-1 2
0 5
1 4
2 8
3 3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=x,ylabel=y,height=5cm,width=5cm,
         xmax=2,xmin=-2]
\addplot[no markers] table[x=x,y=y] {test.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but it makes the graph look different to all the others made with \datavisualization.

Comment: You can customize the graphs with axis options. In fact, why are you using `\datavisualization` instead of `pgfplots` (just curious, I didn't know about this `tikz`'s data feature)

Comment: Did a little research on the matter http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198528/tikz-pgf-3-0-datavisualization-vs-pgfplots it's more of an opinion sort of answer but it's a fact that `pgfplots` is older and therefore is more developed than `datavisualization`. I have used `pgfplots` a lot and I know that there are **MANY** customizable options for plotting, especially for standardizing plots (you can use global options) so, IMHO change to `pgfplots` if you are still in time.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I need to figure out if it takes more time to switch to `pgfplots` or to cut the range in the csv file by hand. I chose `datavisualization` because I did all of my plots with TikZ, so I was just looking up its manual to see how to do plots.

Comment: No problem, though Ìt wasn't really a correct answer, since you asked using `\datavisualiyation` (I looked for it and didn't found any, so posted that one). I would say that for future plots, future you would thank you for switching to `pgfplots`. But for the current document your doing, it's really up to you.