# pgfplots vs datavisualization – 2019 review

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-datavisualization

Ti*k*Z' `datavisualization` library and the package `pgfplots` (based on Ti*k*Z) both produce pretty nice plots in LaTeX. To someone starting to do that, what are the differences between the two and what may make one preferable to the other?

---

There is [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66264/tikz-datavisualization-or-pgfplots) from 2012 and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198528/tikz-pgf-3-0-datavisualization-vs-pgfplots/204872) from 2014 basically asking the same question.

- In the 2012 one the answer is that `datavisualization` is still experimental and thus recommends using `pgfplots`.
- In the 2014 answer states that both are reasonable options. The differences pointed out here are

  - `pgfplots` is more mature
  - `datavisualization` is a bit more verbose

---

So, what is the current state of affairs? As a start, here are my thoughts after skimming through both documentations. Please expand on them and correct me, where I got the wrong impression.

- `pgfplots` seems to support more plot types by default.
- In `datavisualization` it seems to be very easy to add new plot types. Is the same true for `pgfplots`?
- `datavisualization` is an inbuilt solution. This guarantees a very high degree of interoperability and consistency in the syntax with the rest of Ti*k*Z.
- Both seem to come with very nice defaults.
- I assume that both allow changing every aspects of how each elements of the plot is visualized.
- `pgfplots` has a much larger user base, which means more help here.
- Are there any differences in the capability to handle large amounts of input data?
- Since `datavisualization` was added to Ti*k*Z *after* `pgfplots` already existed, I assume that the author deemed some of the design choices in `pgfplots` suboptimal.

Comment: I don't think a lot of people (or maybe even no one) uses `datavisualization`.  At least on GitHub there are only [very few bug reports for that component](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=label%3Adatavisualization).  On top I think it doesn't work with `fpu`, so the precision and accessible data range is very limited.

Comment: @HenriMenke On page 843 of the manual it says: "Because of this, the data visualization engine does not use `pgf`’s standard representation of numbers
and TeX dimensions and is does not use the standard parser when reading numbers in a data point. Instead, the `fpu` library, described in Section 56, is used to handle numbers."

Comment: I see, I only remember getting more `! Dimension too large` with `datavisualization` than with `pgfplots`.

Comment: AFAIK datavisualization has no equivalent of `\addplot3`. So you may want to specify the application range.

Comment: @user121799 I intend this question not to be tied to a specific application, so better support for 3D plotting is certainly a relevant difference between the two. If someone only cares about 2D, they can still decide to use the other option. (As I understand it, `datavisualization` in principle supports an arbitrary number of dimensions. However, it seems to only provide predefined axis systems for 2D plotting at the moment.)

Comment: @schtandard It is not just the dimensions but 3d ordering that is important here. `pgfplots` makes use of stuff that is part of `pgfplotstable`, too, which allows you to draw the stuff in the foreground last, such that it really looks 3d-like. This is a highly nontrivial achievement IMHO which for me makes the choice easy. If I was sure that I only need 2d plots, this question would be more delicate. Note also that I do not believe that the motivation for `datavisualization` was that there was something wrong with `pgfplots`.

Comment: @user121799 If I remember correctly, `datavisualization` was developed in parallel to `pgfplots` at a time when Till was not fully aware that both projects would have overlapping scope.  Also it seems to me that `datavisualization` is more geared towards simple graphs in say school text books, whereas `pgfplots` is designed for publication-ready graphs in scientific articles.

Comment: @HenriMenke Why do you address this comment at me, I do not disagree with any of this, nor does your add anything substantial to my comments above. I feel you should address it to the OP.

Answer (score 7):

I cannot fully answer the question, but I'd say that there are two options.

1. You cannot exclude that at a given point you want to produce 3d plots such as surface plots with either of these packages.
2. You only want to produce 2-dimensional plots.

In the first case, you will inevitably have to rely on `pgfplots`. This is because `pgfplots` supports 3d ordering (all the keys of the type `z buffer=sort` and friends come into play here), which `datavisalization` currently does not.  Most users like to have universal styles. For instance, you may want to have the arrow heads look the same for all plots and so on. This is arguably easiest if you do everything with the same package, which is pgfplots in this case.

In the second case, the situation is less clear. `pgfplots` is extremely powerful, but also somewhat complex. For instance, `\foreach` loops require special attention. This is nothing that cannot be learned, but if you have a very clear scope you may eventually be better off with `datavisualization`. (I personally would recommend to learn to deal with these pitfalls, they are to my knowledge all documented in the manual.)

Overall I feel that new users will in most cases be better off with `pgfplots`, also because there are way more examples available. For instance, there are about 100 times more posts tagged `pgfplots` on this site than `datavisualization`. True, some of them are duplicates, but nevertheless there are many more examples.

Needless to say that there are alternatives like `tikz-3dplot`, `pstricks` and `asymptote`. `tikz-3dplot` is a very powerful tool for drawing sketches and `asymptote` has a real 3d engine and many features that sometimes do not get as much appreciated as they could.