# How to create simple graph in latex

Tags: graphs

How to create simple graph in latex. x,y axis with straight line drawn at (0,0) at 45 degress through the x,y axis.

The graphs here are excellent but just too complicated for newcommers.

---

here is the link

[image]

Comment: Hi tmk, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). In addition to the answers below, have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60428/6621 and [the other questions tagged with pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged)/pgfplots

Comment: @tmk I have merged the two accounts you seem to have, and moved your link into the question. However, the picture does not seem to be much like the plot you describe.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for the intervention. Am not an admin or super user to do those stuff.:-)

Answer (score 9):

You can use `TikZ` (the [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) is really great and it has numerous examples; there's also a [Minimal introduction to TikZ](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (1,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,1) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[blue] +(225:1.4) -- +(45:1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (5,0); 
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5);
\draw[blue] (0,0) -- +(45:7);
\foreach \i/\text in {1.4/year,2.8/age,4.2/type,5.6/speed}
  \draw[fill=white,draw=blue] (45:\i) circle (2pt) node[left,xshift=-2pt] at (45:\i) {\text};
\node[anchor=west] at (0,-10pt) {Colour};
\node[anchor=east] at (5,-10pt) {Make};
\node[anchor=east,text width=1cm,align=left] at (-10pt,10pt) {Engine};
\node[anchor=east,text width=1cm,align=left] at (-10pt,4.8) {Car};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo, well appreciated. will try to customize this sample, spent all day on this. the graph is actually a right angle one with straight line drawn from (0,0) to any number range. trying to label x,y and specifying my position e.g. top left, bottom left would not work. Also, tried getting dotted circle on the straight line through (0,0) to contain text but, that also was a nightmare.

Comment: sorry everyone, the boxes around the text in the graph are not needed. this was drawn using ms word.

Comment: @tmk I've updated my answer with a possible simple way to draw your diagram.

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo, your contribution is well appreciated. I have just been looking at the "pgfplots" you recommended, it is great and will get myself up to scratch in this. thank you.

Answer (score 8):

For plotting functions or data, [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)  which is based on TikZ, is useful. A simple example is given below, and the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) has many more.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center]
  \addplot [mark=none] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]