# tikzpicture in minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Can I set the exact width to a tikzpicture?  I thought so, with "width", but I tried this:

```
\colorbox{gray}{
\begin{minipage}{.33\textwidth}
adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk 
\colorbox{yellow}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,ymax=3.5, ymin=-3.5]
  \addplot[blue, domain=-5.8:5.8,samples=30] {sin((180/pi)*x)};
% ....
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{minipage}
}
```

(-- sorry: I cannot post images--)
but the yellow rectangle is smaller than \textwidth.
I set it to \textwidth+1.3cm (seems to be a fixed margin) and does more or less what I expect, but is there a cleaner solution?
Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 9):

The `width` option in PGFPlots only results in approximately the correct size, because it works with static assumptions about the space taken up by the labels. To scale a plot exactly to some specified width, you have a couple of options: See [pgfplots: how can I scale to text width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36297/pgfplots-how-can-i-scale-to-text-width).

One approach that seems particularly well suited here is to use Patrick Häckler's excellent package `tikzscale`. To use it, you need to keep the code for the `tikzpicture` in a separate file (which is a good idea in real documents anyway, because it keeps everything much more maintainable), which you then include using `\includepicture[width=...]{<filename>}`. `tikzscale` then does some magic in the background, and you end up with a perfectly sized plot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\usepackage{tikzscale}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{graph1.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,ymax=3.5, ymin=-3.5]
  \addplot[blue, domain=-5.8:5.8,samples=30] {sin((180/pi)*x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}


\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt} % Otherwise you introduce padding in the yellow box

\begin{document}
\colorbox{gray}{%
\begin{minipage}{.33\textwidth}
adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk adfjk 
\colorbox{yellow}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph1.tikz}}
\end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's copied from the OP but you have a word space at the start and end of the gray colorbox which is probably not desired.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Cheers! I wish I could somehow give you some TikZ reputation for that, but alas...