# Create standalone pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to write a sample code to be used as a template to generate pictures that will be latter included in a paper. At this stage, the pictures are only plots.

I have the following code. But it does not respect the specified `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`. What is missing?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
paperwidth=52.65mm,
paperheight=47.75mm,
margin=0mm,
}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Like in main document 
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}

\newcommand*{\Filename}{test.dat} % name of data file

\usepackage{pgfplots}
% Default options for plots
\pgfplotsset{%
compat=newest,
compat/show suggested version=false,
every axis/.append style={thick},
width=\paperwidth,
height=\paperheight,
%ymin=0,ymax=0.5,
%xmin=-4,xmax=4,
tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
label style={font=\footnotesize},
grid=both,
xlabel={}, ylabel={},
%y label style={at={(0.03,0.5)}},
legend style={
    %at={(1,1)},
    %anchor=north,
    %legend columns=1,
    %cells={anchor=west},
    font=\footnotesize,
    %rounded corners=1pt,
},
enlargelimits=false
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=1] {\Filename};
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=2] {\Filename};
%\addplot table[x index=0,y index=3] {\Filename};
%\legend{1, 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `\Filename` has the following structure:

```
-4.15026086e+00 7.25473468e-05 1.41017490e-04
-3.86659676e+00 2.26169966e-04 1.05763117e-04
-3.58293265e+00 6.50582962e-04 5.99324332e-04
-3.29926855e+00 1.72673142e-03 1.55119239e-03
-3.01560444e+00 4.22864523e-03 4.44205093e-03
-2.73194034e+00 9.55503020e-03 1.00827505e-02
-2.44827623e+00 1.99212796e-02 2.09410973e-02
-2.16461213e+00 3.83227576e-02 3.75811611e-02
-1.88094802e+00 6.80221925e-02 6.63487290e-02
-1.59728392e+00 1.11403505e-01 1.17220789e-01
-1.31361981e+00 1.68345470e-01 1.65484024e-01
-1.02995571e+00 2.34724472e-01 2.39377189e-01
-7.46291604e-01 3.01974074e-01 2.99380131e-01
-4.62627499e-01 3.58455543e-01 3.52790505e-01
-1.78963394e-01 3.92604521e-01 3.91112008e-01
1.04700711e-01 3.96761612e-01 3.99960856e-01
3.88364816e-01 3.69963048e-01 3.68619719e-01
6.72028921e-01 3.18303494e-01 3.16725282e-01
9.55693026e-01 2.52684624e-01 2.53091140e-01
1.23935713e+00 1.85084726e-01 1.84944438e-01
1.52302124e+00 1.25088302e-01 1.24624207e-01
1.80668534e+00 7.80040529e-02 7.93575925e-02
2.09034945e+00 4.48819784e-02 4.54428861e-02
2.37401355e+00 2.38276477e-02 2.55241657e-02
2.65767766e+00 1.16719845e-02 1.14576711e-02
2.94134176e+00 5.27548738e-03 5.11188401e-03
3.22500587e+00 2.20006153e-03 1.86848174e-03
3.50866997e+00 8.46567166e-04 1.12813992e-03
3.79233408e+00 3.00567741e-04 2.82034980e-04
4.07599818e+00 9.84640435e-05 1.41017490e-04
```

Comment: It works for me, if I remove `geometry` all together and set `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight` manually (or just assign the values directly in the `\pgfplotsset`). Additionally, the class option `tikz` may help. And/or `crop=false`.

Comment: It didn't work for me. If I look in the pdf properties it gives me paper size 44 × 39 mm, and not what I defined!

Comment: You can try with `\documentclass{article}` instead. Here it also works with `standalone` if you use `\documentclass[crop=false]{standalone}` as Qrrbrbirlbel noted.

Comment: The problem here is `pgfplots`. It does not scale the whole picture according to the `width` and `height` keys but somehow different. This led to the `tikzscale` package (originated from TeX.sx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `width` and `height` keys do not work as one expects. I refer to section 4.9 “Scaling Options”, pp. 199ff. of the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), and [pgfplots: how can I scale to text width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36297/16595).

The problem is, that only the axis units are scaled and the labels and descriptions heights/widths are only estimated and …

Here’s my proposal:

Use `tikzscale` in combination with `crop=false`.

Somewhere TeX thinks that the resulting TikZ picture is higher than the paper height so I subtracted manually `0.001pt` and it fits on one site.

### Code

```
\documentclass[crop=false]{standalone}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    paperwidth=52.65mm,
    paperheight=47.75mm,
    margin=0mm,
}

\newcommand*{\Filename}{101992} % name of data file
\begin{filecontents*}{\Filename.dat}
-4.15026086e+00 7.25473468e-05 1.41017490e-04
-3.86659676e+00 2.26169966e-04 1.05763117e-04
-3.58293265e+00 6.50582962e-04 5.99324332e-04
-3.29926855e+00 1.72673142e-03 1.55119239e-03
-3.01560444e+00 4.22864523e-03 4.44205093e-03
-2.73194034e+00 9.55503020e-03 1.00827505e-02
-2.44827623e+00 1.99212796e-02 2.09410973e-02
-2.16461213e+00 3.83227576e-02 3.75811611e-02
-1.88094802e+00 6.80221925e-02 6.63487290e-02
-1.59728392e+00 1.11403505e-01 1.17220789e-01
-1.31361981e+00 1.68345470e-01 1.65484024e-01
-1.02995571e+00 2.34724472e-01 2.39377189e-01
-7.46291604e-01 3.01974074e-01 2.99380131e-01
-4.62627499e-01 3.58455543e-01 3.52790505e-01
-1.78963394e-01 3.92604521e-01 3.91112008e-01
1.04700711e-01 3.96761612e-01 3.99960856e-01
3.88364816e-01 3.69963048e-01 3.68619719e-01
6.72028921e-01 3.18303494e-01 3.16725282e-01
9.55693026e-01 2.52684624e-01 2.53091140e-01
1.23935713e+00 1.85084726e-01 1.84944438e-01
1.52302124e+00 1.25088302e-01 1.24624207e-01
1.80668534e+00 7.80040529e-02 7.93575925e-02
2.09034945e+00 4.48819784e-02 4.54428861e-02
2.37401355e+00 2.38276477e-02 2.55241657e-02
2.65767766e+00 1.16719845e-02 1.14576711e-02
2.94134176e+00 5.27548738e-03 5.11188401e-03
3.22500587e+00 2.20006153e-03 1.86848174e-03
3.50866997e+00 8.46567166e-04 1.12813992e-03
3.79233408e+00 3.00567741e-04 2.82034980e-04
4.07599818e+00 9.84640435e-05 1.41017490e-04
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\Filename.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=1] {\Filename.dat};
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=2] {\Filename.dat};
\legend{1, 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgfplots,tikzscale}
\begin{document}\noindent
\includegraphics[height=\paperheight-.001pt,width=\paperwidth]{\Filename.tikz}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just knew `\includegraphics` can accept `.tikz`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the tikzscale package. I didn't know it. Your solution seems to work very good. But the `width` and `height` in `pgfplots` are useless?