# How to align two plots horizontally

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment

I want to align these two plots horizontally:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=1995,
            xmax=2010,
            ymode=log,
            xtick={1975,1980,...,2015},
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
            xlabel={Year},
            ylabel={Cost of gene synthesis $(\$/base$)},
        ]
            \addplot coordinates {(1998,30) (2001,15) (2002,10) (2003,5) (2006,0) (2007,0.7)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

and

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=1975,
            xmax=2010,
            ymode=log,
            xtick={1975,1980,...,2015},
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
            xlabel={Year},
            ylabel={Length in base pairs},
        ]
            \addplot coordinates {(1978,207) (1990,2100) (1995,2700) (2003,7500) (2005,14600) (2006,32000) (2009,583000)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I tried to use `\subfigure` but without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, using the [`subcaption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subcaption) package as you desired

[image: screenshot]

I took the liberty of moving your `ylabel` text into the caption. I set the `width=\textwidth` too.

You might like to explore `scale only axis` it's quite useful- I've left it in the preamble as a comment for you to play with.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: true}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
%                    scale only axis,       % otherwise width won't be as intended: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36297/pgfplots-how-can-i-scale-to-text-width
%                    }}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                    xmin=1995,
                    xmax=2010,
                    ymode=log,
                    xtick={1975,1980,...,2015},
                    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
                    xlabel={Year},
                    width=\textwidth,
                ]
                \addplot coordinates {(1998,30) (2001,15) (2002,10) (2003,5) (2006,0) (2007,0.7)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Cost of gene synthesis ($\$/base$)},
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                    xmin=1975,
                    xmax=2010,
                    ymode=log,
                    xtick={1975,1985,...,2015},
                    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
                    xlabel={Year},
                    width=\textwidth,
                ]
                \addplot coordinates {(1978,207) (1990,2100) (1995,2700) (2003,7500) (2005,14600) (2006,32000) (2009,583000)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Length in base pairs}
    \end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am experiencing now a new problem, I have to put the entire figure in two column article, and I want to center the figure as if the article was a single column because it compiles in rows in my 2-column article

Comment: @microarm15 that will probably be a new question- you might like to explore `figure*` :)

Answer (score 2):

I usually just place them together in a `center` environment:

```
\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis} ... \end{axis} \end{tikzpicture}
 \hfil
 \begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis} ... \end{axis} \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

There is also `\usepgfplots{groupplots}` and its associated matrix-like arrangement, documented in Section 5.5 of the `pgfplots` manual.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I faced the same problem, I have to remove the ylabel from the first graph and still the final plot in two stages

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about both what you want and what your problem is, then.