# Argument to \input or \include statement?

Tags: tikz-pgf, input, scaling, matlab2tikz

I produce a lot of plots in Matlab which I export to TikZ with `matlab2tikz`. In `matlab2tikz` I can specify the plot `width` and `height`, for instance. This works out quite nicely, but as I write my document I see that I should have changed the `width` and `height` to different values for several plots. Now, this is of course something I either could do in the `matlab2tikz` call or directly in the `.tex` file output from `matlab2tikz`. I have quite significant amounts of plots and most of them are created in "automated" procedures, so it would be nice if I could pass an argument to `\input` (or similar) which could manipulate the `width` and/or `height` of the plot. Something like:

```
\input[w=0.4,h=0.2]{plotfile}
```

and have something like this in `plotfile`:

```
\begin{axis}[%
width=w\textwidth,
height=h\textwidth,
]
```

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: you don't want to use `\include` -- that always starts a new page, and is most appropriate for pulling in new chapters.

Comment: Take a look at the `tikzscale` package. It’s written for scaling the picture to the exact size specified (unlike the `width` and `height` option of `pgfplots` which doesn’t factor in the labels).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel : As far as I know, *not rescaling the label* should be the wanted result, for typographically-consistent document.

Comment: @T.Verron Nobody said anything about re-scaling the label. In fact, that is one major argument for using `tikzscale`. `pgfplots` doesn’t know the exact dimensions of the labels so it doesn’t get the plot’s resulting width/height precisely as specified. See [pgfplots: how can I scale to text width?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36297)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel : Oh, ok, my misunderstanding, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about defining it this way?

```
\newlength{\figurewidth}
\newlength{\figureheight}

\newcommand{\myinputaux}[2][1]{%
  \def\myheight{#1}
  \setlength\figureheight{\myheight\textwidth}
  \setlength\figurewidth{\mywidth\textwidth} 
  \input{#2}}

\newcommand{\myinput}[1][1]{%
  \def\mywidth{#1}
  \myinputaux}
```

You would then call this function like this:

```
\myinput[0.4][0.2]{plotfile} % the first optional is the width, the second is the height
```

and execute `matlab2tikz` with

```
matlab2tikz( 'plotfile', 'height', '\figureheight', 'width', '\figurewidth' );
```

Note that this answer is purely theoretical, based on the readme for `matlab2tikz`. I couldn't test it "for real".

Comment: Oooh, that would be a nifty solution. However, I get loads of errors when trying to compile with your solution, `missing \begin{document}` at the line of `\input{#2}}` being one of them...

Comment: Absolutely no idea why I got that error message. Made a new, stripped document, and it works. NICE DUDE!

Comment: @egreg's edit (thanks to him!) might be what fixed your mysterious problem. I had forgotten a backslash in the definition of `\myinputaux`.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't tested it with `\include` statement but you can localize your axis options and let them executed after the axis options.

EDIT: Oh and of course your `\input` is going to replace the `tikzpicture`s below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

{
\pgfplotsset{execute at begin axis={\pgfplotsset{width=3cm}}} %<-- Only inside this group
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=10cm,domain=-360:360]
    \addplot {sin(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=10cm,domain=-360:360]
    \addplot {sin(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So this allows you to set some kind of `global width` which you can limit to a certain scope?

Comment: @Holene It forces an option to be executed as the last one as if we have added manually to each axis environment. Scoping limits its effect.