# Externally set ymin, ymax, xmin and xmax with pgfplotset

Tags: pgfplots

According to percusses answer in [Argument to \input or \include statement?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111561/argument-to-input-or-include-statement) both `height` and `width` in the `axis` environment in `PGFplots` may be set externally (outside the `axis` environment) with a nested `\pgfplotsset` statement:

```
\pgfplotsset{execute at begin axis={\pgfplotsset{width=5cm}}}
```

However, if I try to apply the same concept to `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` according to the answer suggested by Piotr, `pgfplotsset` doesn't seem to override the settings given within the `axis` environment.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
{ % begin outer pgfplotsset scope
\pgfplotsset{ymax=5, ymin=1, execute at begin axis={\pgfplotsset{width=5cm}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=10cm, ymin=0]
    \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
} % end outer pgfplotsset scope
\end{document}
```

which produces the following graph, where `ymin` clearly is `0`, though I just set it `ymin=1` in `pgfplotsset`.

[image]

---

## What I want to achieve

Set `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` from outside the `axis` environment (in a similar way as I do with `width` applying `execute at begin axis` in `pgsplotsset`), even though they also will be specified in `\begin{axis}[]`. The external call to `xmin` etc. should override the values set in `\begin{axis}[]`.

---

Comment: `execute at begin axis` is probably executed *after* the option you provide. This does not happen if you use the `every axis` (which is applied before any local options) style: `every axis/.append style={width=5cm}`. The `ymin=0` overwrites the `ymin=1` setting from before.

Comment: So I'll still have my overriding problem... :p

Comment: Could you re-phrase your question? What is your problem? What do you want to achieve? — The `execute at begin axis` code is executed after the `[ ]` axis options. Of course `ymin=0` overwrites a previous set `ymin=1`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Ah, damn, it's quite obvious I haven't clarified what  I really want to achieve. I'm sorry. Reformulated question coming up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, depending on what they option actually does, we can simply deactivate it.

The `overwrite option` key takes its argument in the form of `<key> with <value>` (the spaces are needed), sets the key to that value and than disables the key altogether by assigning an empty `/.code`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{overwrite option/.style args={#1 with #2}{#1=#2,#1/.code=}}
\begin{document}
{ % begin outer pgfplotsset scope
\pgfplotsset{ymax=5, overwrite option=ymin with 1, execute at begin axis={\pgfplotsset{width=5cm}}}% the ymin key doesn't work anymore
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=10cm, ymin=0]
    \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
} % end outer pgfplotsset scope
% the ymin key works as usual
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `\pgfplotsset{xmin=...}` within desired scope:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
{ % begin pgfplotsset scope
\pgfplotsset{xmin=0, xmax=3, ymin=1, ymax=5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=10cm]
    \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
} % end pgfplotsset scope
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=10cm]
    \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This will result with:
[image: result]

Comment: This is the kind of behaviour I'm looking for! However: with `width`, `pgfplotsset` overrides the setting in the `axis` environment. Somehow, this doesn't happen with `xmin`, `xmax` (and so on). Do you know why?

Comment: I'll reformulate the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for ist the `every axis post/.append style` key, which is - to my knowledge - executed after the previous axis styles, and thus overwrites them. Thus the solution is very easy:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,convert={ghostscript, density={500}}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
{ % begin outer pgfplotsset scope
\pgfplotsset{ymax=5, execute at begin axis={\pgfplotsset{width=5cm}},
every axis post/.append style={ymin=1}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=10cm, ymin=0]
    \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
} % end outer pgfplotsset scope
\end{document}
```

[image: plot]