# font size scaling and node placement issues using pgfplots and tikzscale

Tags: pgfplots, tikzscale

From the `tikzscale` documentation I understand, that it is supposed to keep font sizes constant. However, this does not seem to apply to axis ticks or axis labels from `pgfplots`' `axis` environment. Also, node placement seems to be messed up. This is illustrated in the following example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{font-size.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  width=150pt,
  height=150pt,
  xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,
  xlabel=xlabel,
  ylabel=ylabel,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates{ 
  (-0.9,-0.9)
  (0.9,0.9)
  };
  \node[anchor=west] at (axis cs:-1,0) {01};
  \coordinate (a) at (axis cs:-1,0);
  \end{axis}
  \node[anchor=west,red] at (a) {02};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

Some text in font size 10pt.
\input{font-size.tikz}
\includegraphics[width=250pt]{font-size.tikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]
In the first plot, created without `tikzscale`, all labels and nodes have the correct font size and node "02" is placed correctly. In the second plot, however, font sizes for the labels are obviously larger. The same holds for node "01". Interestingly, node "02" has the correct font size, but the placement is wrong. Is there a way to correctly scale the `axis` (or `groupplot`) environment while preserving the labels' and nodes' font sizes as well as placing nodes at the correct position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't specify

```
width=150pt,
height=150pt,
```

to the axis in the options. This doesn't make sense since you are controlling the dimensions from outside. Further, there is also `axisratio` key provided if you want different axis ratios.

```
\documentclass[10pt,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{font-size.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
  \begin{axis}[
%  width=150pt,               %% don't give this
%  height=150pt,              %% don't give this
  xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,
  xlabel=xlabel,
  ylabel=ylabel,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates{
  (-0.9,-0.9)
  (0.9,0.9)
  };
  \node[anchor=west] at (axis cs:-1,0) {01};
  \coordinate (a) at (axis cs:-1,0);
  \end{axis}
  \node[anchor=west,red] at (a) {02};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

Some text in font size 10pt.
\input{font-size.tikz}
\includegraphics[width=250pt]{font-size.tikz}   %% use width=250pt,axisratio=2 to see the change
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for groupplots. I posted a follow-up question here: [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174013/scaling-multi-column-groupplot-while-maintaining-font-size-and-node-placement)