# scaling multi column groupplot while maintaining font size and node placement

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots, tikzscale

This is a follow-up to two previous questions:
1: [font size scaling and node placement issues using pgfplots and tikzscale](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169574/font-size-scaling-and-node-placement-issues-using-pgfplots-and-tikzscale)
2: [Scaling a multi-column TikZ/pgfplots groupplot to page width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118627/scaling-a-multi-column-tikz-pgfplots-groupplot-to-page-width/118655#118655)

I would like to scale a multi-column groupplot to a certain width (usually `\textwidth`
) while maintaining font size and node placement. From question 1 I got that, when using `tikzscale`, one should not define `hight` and/or `width` for the `axis` environment in order to maintain font sizes and node placement. The answer to question 2 is, that I should use `tikzscale` to scale `groupplots` to a desired overall width. But if one does not define `hight` and `width`, then the combination of `groupplot` and `tikzscale` will produce an error:

> ! Package pgfplots Error: Error: Plot height `-77.46211pt' is too small. This c
>   annot be implemented while maintaining constant size for labels. Sorry, label s
>   izes are only approximate. You will need to adjust your height..

The plot will not be scaled correctly.
The short version of my question would be, "How can I scale a multi-column groupplot to a certain width while still maintaining font size and node placement?''
The following MWE illustrates the issue.

```
\documentclass[10pt,crop,varwidth=250pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{A.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
        group size =2 by 1,
        horizontal sep = 1cm
        },
  width=125pt,
  height=125pt,
  xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,
  xlabel=xlabel,
  ]
  \nextgroupplot[
  ylabel=ylabel,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates{  (-0.9,-0.9)  (0.9,0.9)  };
  \node[anchor=west] at (axis cs:-1,0) {01};
  \coordinate (a) at (axis cs:-1,0);
  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot coordinates{  (-0.9,-0.9)  (0.9,0.9)  };  
  \end{groupplot}
  \node[anchor=west,red] at (a) {02};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{B.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
  \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
        group size =2 by 1,
        horizontal sep = 1cm
        },
%   width=125pt,               %% this is now omitted
%   height=125pt,              %% this is now omitted
  xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,
  xlabel=xlabel,
  ]
  \nextgroupplot[
  ylabel=ylabel,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates{  (-0.9,-0.9)  (0.9,0.9)  };
  \node[anchor=west] at (axis cs:-1,0) {01};
  \coordinate (a) at (axis cs:-1,0);
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot coordinates{  (-0.9,-0.9)  (0.9,0.9)  };
  \end{groupplot}
  \node[anchor=west,red] at (a) {02};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\input{A.tikz}
Manually scaling height and width of the plots requires a lot of tries until an ``acceptable'' result is reached. At least the font size and node placement are correct.
\includegraphics[width=250pt]{A.tikz}
Width and height are defined and tikzscale is used. The plots scale nicely to the desired width, but font size and node placement problems occur.
\input{B.tikz}
Without defined height and width and without tikzscale, the plots are too large to fit the desired textwidth. Font size and node placement work fine.
\includegraphics[width=250pt]{B.tikz}
No definition of width and height, but using tikzscale will produce an error. The plot is not scaled correctly but font size and node placement look fine.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is an option to typeset four independent TikZ plots and put them together without grouping?

Comment: If there is a practicable way, yes. But that would propably mean loosing all the comfort that `groupplots` has to offer (e.g. size of the axes, correct placement despite different labels...)

Answer (score 8):

**Disclaimer:** This is not a complete answer as it only deals with plot width, label font sizes etc., but not with the node size and placement. It'd be too long as a comment unfortunately.

---

I have found that it is possible to get proper font sizes when using `groupplots` by compensating for the horizontal spacing between plots.

Your `\includegraphics` command is still invoked with the option `width=\textwidth`, but the width of each plot within the `groupplots` environment has to be set to `1/x*\textwidth-y`, where `x` is the number of group plots placed horizontally and `y` is the horizontal separation specified.

## Output:

[image: Output]

As far as I can tell, the width of the `tikzscale`-d figures is close to perfection and the fonts are not distorted.

But unfortunately this does not also solve the node placement issue. I hope this is a good starting point and someone else can help you with that. I use `tikzscale` very often as well and it'd be great to have a robust solution for scaling `groupplots`.

## Solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{notikzscale.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
      group size=2 by 1,
      horizontal sep=2cm,
    },
    scale only axis,
    width=0.38*\textwidth,
    height=3cm,
    xlabel=$x$,
  ]

    \nextgroupplot[ylabel={This}]
      \addplot coordinates { (-0.9,-0.9) (0.9,0.9) };
      \node[anchor=west] (a) at (axis cs:-1,0) {01};

    \nextgroupplot[ylabel={That}]
      \addplot coordinates { (-0.9,-0.9) (0.9,0.9) };

  \end{groupplot}

  \node[anchor=west,red] at (a) {0.2};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{2by1.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
      group size=2 by 1,
      horizontal sep=2cm,
    },
    width=1/2*\textwidth-2cm,
    height=3cm,
    xlabel=$x$,
  ]

    \nextgroupplot[ylabel={This}]
      \addplot coordinates { (-0.9,-0.9) (0.9,0.9) };
      \node[anchor=west] (a) at (axis cs:-1,0) {01};

    \nextgroupplot[ylabel={That}]
      \addplot coordinates { (-0.9,-0.9) (0.9,0.9) };

  \end{groupplot}

  \node[anchor=west,red] at (a) {0.2};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{3by1.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
      group size=3 by 1,
      horizontal sep=1cm,
    },
    scale only axis,
    width=1/3*\textwidth-1cm,
    height=3cm,
    xlabel=$x$,
  ]

    \nextgroupplot[ylabel={This}]
      \addplot coordinates { (-0.9,-0.9) (0.9,0.9) };
      \node[anchor=west] (a) at (axis cs:-1,0) {01};

    \nextgroupplot
      \addplot coordinates { (-0.9,-0.9) (0.9,0.9) };

    \nextgroupplot
      \addplot coordinates { (-0.9,-0.9) (0.9,0.9) };

  \end{groupplot}

  \node[anchor=west,red] at (a) {0.2};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{4by1.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
      group size=4 by 1,
      horizontal sep=1cm,
    },
    width=1/4*\textwidth-1cm,
    height=3cm,
    xlabel=$x$,
  ]

    \nextgroupplot[ylabel={This}]
      \addplot coordinates { (-0.9,-0.9) (0.9,0.9) };
      \node[anchor=west] (a) at (axis cs:-1,0) {01};

    \nextgroupplot
      \addplot coordinates { (-0.9,-0.9) (0.9,0.9) };

    \nextgroupplot
      \addplot coordinates { (-0.9,-0.9) (0.9,0.9) };

    \nextgroupplot
      \addplot coordinates { (-0.9,-0.9) (0.9,0.9) };

  \end{groupplot}

  \node[anchor=west,red] at (a) {0.2};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
This does not use \texttt{tikzscale}. Manually-sized.
\begin{center}
\input{notikzscale.tikz}
\end{center}

\vspace{0.5cm}

The below use \texttt{tikzscale}.

\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2by1.tikz}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3by1.tikz}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{4by1.tikz}
\end{document}
```