# tikzscale package not working with group plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots, tikzscale

I'm trying to scale a pgfplots that uses group plots but something is not working properly. This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
  total={6in,9in},%
  body={111.5mm,185.6mm},%
  head=10pt,
  centering,showframe,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots, colorbrewer}
\usepackage{tikzscale}


\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=1.\linewidth,axisratio=1]{group_plot.tikz}
\input{group_plot.tikz}
\end{document}
```

and the file `group_plot.tikz` is simply:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\begin{groupplot}[cycle list/Dark2, group style={group name=myplot, group size= 2 by 1, horizontal sep=0.5em}, every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.4mm, line join=round},
      axis lines = middle,
      enlargelimits = true,
      x axis line style = {thick,-stealth},
      y axis line style = {thick,-stealth},
       legend style={font=\footnotesize, at={(0.61,0)}, anchor=south, draw=none, yshift=-23pt, fill=white, fill opacity=0.9, 
      /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.2cm}},
      legend columns=3,
      xmin=-1,xmax=1,
      ymin=-1,ymax=1.,
%      every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.east)}, yshift=3pt},
]

\nextgroupplot[
      cycle list name = Dark2,
      xlabel=$\xi$,
      ylabel={$\xi^i$},
      xtick={-1,1},
      ytick={1},
      every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.north)}, xshift=8pt,yshift=-2pt},
    ]
    % use TeX as calculator:
    \addplot + [mark=none, domain=-1:1] {x};
\nextgroupplot[
      cycle list name = Dark2,
      xlabel=$\xi$,
      ylabel={$L_i(\xi)$},
      xtick={-1,1},
      ytick={1},
      every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.north)}, xshift=15pt,yshift=-2pt},
    ]
    % use TeX as calculator:
    \addplot + [mark=none, domain=-1:1] {x};        
\end{groupplot}
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
            
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get a result that doesn't make sense, with the error:

> ./group_plot.tikz:36: Package pgfplots Error: Error: Plot width `-6.1997pt' is too small. This cannot be implemented while maintaining constant size for labels. Sorry, label sizes are only approximate. You will need to adjust your width..

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Isn't this the same issue as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174013/47927 ?

Comment: It's the same issue, but for some reason that post has code that compiles without problem and the one in this post doesn't.

Comment: Please create a MWE showing your problem. Delete all labels, styles, plots - everything that is not needed to show the error/unexpected behaviour.

Comment: The code I wrote is pretty much a MWE, right?

Comment: My guess is that your code is not minimal. Is `colorbrewer` needed to recreate your problem? You already has an answer, so I guess it does not matter now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is the solution you are aiming. But I compile and got the same message with `-6.1997pt` etc. As I did just small changes following [the linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183384/140133) cited in comments, I will only present these parts of the code, the rest remains intact.

#### Changes

Changes are:

1. In your main file, `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}`. This is not mandatory, but results look nicer.

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10} % add
```

2. In your `group_plot.tikz` add the following lines into `\begin{groupplot}`

```
\begin{groupplot}[
...
% add
  width=1/2*\textwidth-2.5cm,
  height=2.5cm
]
```

You edit the values in order to achieve the result you wish.

Those lines were the lines I noticed there weren't in your group define, but they were at the original one, besides, the log message wrote something about `height` and `width`, so that was my best guess.

3. Not mandatory, but I reduced a little bit the size of the figure from 1 to `0.9 \linewidth` in `\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,axisratio=1]{group_plot.tikz}`.

#### Results

**With** `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}`.

[image]

**Without** `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}`.

[image]