# How to use complete width of page in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins

I have drawn an figure which almost takes 80% of width of the page.
So I want it to give full width. If I try it manually, I get warning as overfull \hbox.

Comment: Please post your code/design here.

Comment: The problem is a tex' problem. You want to put a big box (picture) inside a smaller box (text). Tikz can help you with  `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] `.

Comment: Perhaps the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) can be also of interest for you.

Answer (score 13):

try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

        \draw[fill=green] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you have a figure drawn using tikz, you may use the full width by `\resizebox` provided by `graphicx`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  %=========================
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering{
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\input{figurefile.tex}}} %% assuming figurefile is a tikz code
\caption{caption goes here} \label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}
%===========================
\end{document}
```

This can also be done using `adjustbox` package by Martin Scharrer. Actually `adjustbox` offers more functionalities for things like these.