# Scale to fixed width of tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

After looking for something like that [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75449/21930) and searching the site. I haven't found something that works (may be I skipped something important).

I would like an automated way of telling `tikz` the final size of the `tikzpicture`.

I want to draw something and I want `tikz` to calculate automatically the scale to show me the maximum possible. Something like `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale to width = \textwidth]` will scale the figure so the final `tikzpicture` has a width of `\textwidth`. The cool thing would be to make also something like `scale to height = …`, with both forms keeping the original ratio of the `tikzpicture`. But if both are issued at the same time there should be a way of having the final size fixed.

I would like this to work within `tikzpicture` (and not with `scalebox` or `resizebox`) so that the resulting image has the correct font size and line width.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
…% Some magic code
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw (0.5,0.5) node {Center};
\end{tikzpicture}% This should be a square of 1cm x 1cm.

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale to with = 10cm]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw (0.5,0.5) node {Center};
\end{tikzpicture}% This should be a square of 10cm x 10cm with the word in correct size

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale to height = 8cm]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw (0.5,0.5) node {Center};
\end{tikzpicture}% This should be a square of 8cm x 8cm with the word in a correct size

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale to with = 10cm, scale to height = 6cm]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw (0.5,0.5) node {Center};
\end{tikzpicture}% This should be a rectangle of 10cm x 6cm with the word in a correct size/shape

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is where the `tikzscale` package comes in handy. See ([How to scale tikz drawing to paperwidth?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131219/how-to-scale-tikz-drawing-to-paperwidth)).

Comment: I saw it in the tags. But that's NOT handy (in my opinion). Should I move all my figures to external `.tikz` files and then use `\includegraphics[width=10cm]{figure.tikz}`? I think that's far from handy. It would be much better to have that option inside the `tikzpicture` options.

Comment: You can't have an inside solution: one has to process the complete image to get the size, then calculate the scale factor and then reprocess it. To use tikzscale you don't need to move the images to external files: You can use the filecontents to create the external files on the fly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okey. Fair enough. Then this question is can be closed (as a duplicate, may be). **EDIT** Isn't a possible way of having an option in `tikzpicture` which does exactly that: *process the complete image to get the size, then calculate the scale factor and then reprocess it*?

Comment: @Manuel: You can define a new environment `manuelstikzpicture` that wraps around the process described in Ulrike's answer (or you could redefine `tikzpicture` to do the same).

Comment: I will try with the answers of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/how-to-scale-a-tikzpicture-to-textwidth and see if they work (I like the idea of `tikzpicture*` environment). If `tikzscale` is better I will try something.