# Using macros for including tikz graphics

Tags: macros

I am not facing any problem, but I need the opinion of the community.

I am writing a thesis and have a lot of tikz figures in it. So what I do is pre-compile these tikz files to PDF and then include them in the thesis.
This makes the re-compiling of the thesis faster as no longer I have to compile 
the tikz files again and again, when I do minor modification in the text.

I have written a macro to include graphics like this -

```
\newcommand\myIncludeGraphics[2]{
\ifdefined\embedTikzGraphics
    \scalebox{#1}{\input{#2.tikz}}
\else
    \includegraphics[scale=#1]{#2}
\fi
}
```

and I include the graphics like this -

```
\begin{figure}
    \myIncludeGraphics{0.9}{chapters/chap1/Figures/fig1}
\end{figure}
```

Here 0.9 specifies how much to scale the figure. However, sometimes I would like to place two figures side-by-side and then I need to manually calculate the scaling factor.

```
\subfloat[CAP1]{\label{fig:lab1a}{\resizebox{0.5\columnwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{chapters/chap1/Figures/fig1a}}}}
\subfloat[CAP2]{\label{fig:lab1b}{\resizebox{0.5\columnwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{chapters/chap1/Figures/fig1b}}}}
```

This will help me to fit the two figure exactly to column-width of the document. However, I lost the capability of embedded tikz files.

I want some suggestions if I can cover all three scenarios in one macro keeping the code clean. I should be able to use `scaling factor` or `width=\columnwidth`.

If this is not possible, it is fine.
Please excuse, if I didn't define the problem correctly.

Thank You

**UPDATE**

Just to summarize what I am trying to achieve is the following.

- I should be able to use the tikz picture integrated in the main pdf or tikz picture which is compile separately and then included in pdf using includegraphics.
- When using includegraphics, I should be able to specify either `width` of the figure or `scale factor` of the figure.
- When using the tikz picture integrated in main pdf, I will not change the macro in my tex. For example the macro usage will look like `myIncludeGraphics{scalefactor=0.9}{chapters/chap1/Figures/fig1}` or `myIncludeGraphics{figWidth=0.5\columnwidth}{chapters/chap1/Figures/fig1}`. Depending on the first argument, the macro should use `scalebox` or `resizebox`. This is because `scalebox` does not understand `0.5\columnwidth` and the other way round for the `resizebox`.

Comment: You know the externalization library of TikZ (`\usetikzlibrary{external}\tikzexternalize`)? See the TikZ manual, section "50 Externalization Library".

Comment: I use a makefile rule to take the tikz code and a template to generate a PDF out of it. The advantage of it is I can issue a parallel execution of make command so that it takes lesser time than using `externalize`.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6388/21930 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131219/21930 might help.

Comment: @Manuel scaling is not really my problem. My problem is to be able to mention in the `same macro` either scalefactor or width of the image.

Comment: @Raj The problem is (if I understood correctly) that the font size, for instance won't be of the same size. That means, the only way to output correct images with tikz is `scale` and if you want to use, e.g., `width`, you need one of those “tricks” I linked. And, finally, if you want to be able to call both of them, it's just a little hack to tell LaTeX wether to use `scale` or those systems to resize to a fixed length.

Comment: @Manuel sorry for mis-leading question. I am going to use the macro `myIncludeGraphics` for many tikz pictures in my thesis. Some of them require scaling, some of them require a fixed width size. I didn't much care about font size as you mentioned. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Raj I see you don't care. But I hope you understand what I mean (not only font size, but line width, for instance, will also be scaled). I don't see any problem with using one of the packages I suggested (of course, someone must write the code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution to maintain the macro's interface clean is to use a key-val parameter using `pgfkeys`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand\myIncludeGraphics[2][]{
\ifdefined\embedTikzGraphics
    \pgfkeys{
        my include/.cd,
        scale/.store in=\myScaleFactor,
        scale=1,
        width/.initial=0,
        % define here similarly the graphicx keys you want to support
        #1
    }
    \scalebox{\myScaleFactor}{\input{#2.tikz}}
\else
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\myIncludeGraphics{tikzdrawing}
\myIncludeGraphics[scale=0.1]{tikzdrawing}
\myIncludeGraphics[width=.5\columnwidth]{tikzdrawing}

\end{document}
```

Here you can pass to the macro any argument accepted by `graphix` but when `\embedTikzGraphics` is defined you will parse them with `pgfkeys`, extract the scale factor and use that directly.

**Update:** Another option is using `adjustbox`:

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand\myIncludeGraphics[2][]{
\ifdefined\embedTikzGraphics
    \begin{adjustbox}{#1}
        \input{#2.tikz}
    \end{adjustbox}
\else
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
\fi
}
```

Comment: this is very close to what I was looking for. Just have one doubt about your answer. Suppose if I want to make `scale` or `width` a compulsory argument of the macro, is it possible? Also, I wanted to use `resizebox` when I specify width of the figure and `scalebox` (as you showed in your answer) when I specify the scaling factor.

Comment: absolutely! First, the key-val arg does not need to be an optional argument; however there are sensible defaults here so it makes sense to make it optional. Second, you may enforce that at least one is passed by checking that with ifs...but I do not see the usefulness of that...

Comment: Added another option: `adjustbox` accepts the same arguments as `\includegraphics`

Comment: this is perfectly what I was looking for! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

As I already commented, scaling doesn't take in account the widths, sizes, etc. in the TikZ code. It just scales the *result*. With [`tikzscale`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzscale/tikzscale.pdf) you can scale only the coordinates, and have everything draw as it was intended in first place (that's the same that `[scale = X]` does inside the options of `tikzpicture`).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\begin{filecontents}{fig.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[y=.1cm] %
        \draw[ultra thick] (0,0) circle (1);
        \draw[red] (0,0) node {$A$};
        \draw[color=blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\begin{center}
    \resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}{\input{fig.tikz}}%
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{fig.tikz}
\end{center}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

gives you

[image]

where I clearly prefer the right one.

So the solution I propose is, use `tikzscale` with `\includegraphics` and only use `width` or `height`. Of course, one could add the `scale` option, but since the figure is already written on a file, it would be the same as the image on the left, which I think is not correct.

Comment: I now clearly understand your point. thanks for the explanation. In your opinion, one should not use `resizebox` for correct results? Thanks !

Comment: That's it. That's the same that `scale` does in the options of TikZ. For instance, compare `\scalebox{5}{\input{fig.tikz}}` with the same `tikzpicture` but add `scale=5`: `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]…\end{tikzpicture}`.