# scale tikzpicture to enclosing minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to alter the following code, to have the **tikzpicture to have the exact width and height of the `minipage` containing it** (without changing the literal coordinates of course :))?

```
\begin{minipage}{2cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{minipage}
```

Comment: The height of a minipage isn't fixed, but you can use \resizebox{} from the graphics package set set either or both.

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]` ???

Comment: \resizebox{2cm}{2cm}{...} works. Thank you John Kormylo :) [Btw. I do now think it's a stupid question ... in this example it works fine ... it's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do and I realized just now the reason this didnt work in my code is related to another thing ... Sorry!]

Comment: Related Question/Duplicate?: [How to scale a tikzpicture to \textwidth](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/how-to-scale-a-tikzpicture-to-textwidth).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the `\resizebox` *will* scale the picture, it will also scale the text in it. This is usually not desired.

Below, I defined `\MyResizeBox` which measures the width of the picture and then produces the images with an appropriate scale, so that only the graphics are scaled, yet the text remains the same size

[image]

### Notes:

- I added a `\fbox` so that we could see the `minipage` boundary.
- The `tabluar` is only so that I could obtain a nice image to post here -- It is not related to the the solution.
- The `tikzpicture` was packaged into a macro to eliminate repeating the code.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\MyScale}{1}%
\newcommand*{\MyPicture}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\MyScale]
    \draw [ultra thick, blue] (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
    \node at (2,2) {Some text};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\newcommand*{\MyResizeBox}[2]{%
    \sbox0{#2}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\MyScale}{#1/\wd0}%
    #2%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{5.0cm} p{4.0cm} p{4.0cm}}
Original & \verb|\resizebox| & \verb|\MyResizeBox| \\

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
    \MyPicture%
\end{minipage}%
}%
&
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
    \resizebox{3.0cm}{3.0cm}{\MyPicture}%
\end{minipage}%
}%
&
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
    \MyResizeBox{3.0cm}{\MyPicture}%
\end{minipage}%
} \\%
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Haha, did u read my mind? Your solution is exactly what I needed ...