# tikz customized shape too big

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to create a customize shape with tikzpicture within 1 unit, but when I use it, it's almost 2 unit size.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \definecolor{bakcolor}{RGB}{220,150,100}
  \newsavebox\myheadphone
  \begin{lrbox}{\myheadphone}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \def\d{5pt}
      \draw[draw=none,fill={rgb,255:red,220; green,150; blue,100}] (0,0) circle (1);
      \draw[draw=white,line width=\d,line cap=round] (-40:1) arc (-40:220:1);
      \draw[draw=white,fill=white,line width=\d,rounded corners=2pt] (-40:1) rectangle ++(-0.3,-0.6);
      \draw[draw=white,fill=white,line width=\d,rounded corners=2pt] (220:1) rectangle ++(0.3,-0.6);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{lrbox}
  \draw[help lines,] (-2, -2) grid[step={(1,1)}] (2, 2);
  \node[draw] (A) {A};
  \node[circle,fill=bakcolor,right=1cm of A,minimum size=4] (B) {\usebox\myheadphone};
  \draw[->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Obviously:

1. The border of the customized shape too wide.
2. The whole object too big. the minimum size keyword does't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've done is to first make a shape that in itself has a radius slightly larger than 1cm, then you put this shape in a rectangular box, and finally you put that box in a circular `node`. Nodes have an `inner sep`, a padding between the content and the border. As a result, the node you've put the shape in becomes larger than 2cm across. And as marmot rightly says, the `minimum size` defines a lower bound for the node size, if the content of the node is larger, the node becomes larger. That said, you've set `minimum size=4`, without a unit, and in this case the default unit is `pt`, I believe.

Anyways, if you want the headphone symbol to fit within a circle of radius 1cm, reduce the size of it. You might consider using a `pic` instead of a savebox though, see example below. Left is a savebox, right is a `pic`.

The savebox is inherently rectangular, so even if you set the shape of the node containing it to `circle`, the arrow still wouldn't reach the shape. You can circumvent that problem with a negative `inner sep` though, try `\node [inner sep=-8.5pt,circle] (C) at (-2,0) {\usebox\myheadphone};`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{bakcolor}{RGB}{220,150,100}

\tikzset{
  headphone/.pic={
      \def\d{5pt}
      \node[draw=none,fill=bakcolor,minimum size=2cm,circle] (-outline) at (0,0){};
      \begin{scope}[yshift=\d/2]
      \draw[draw=white,line width=\d,line cap=round] (-40:0.6) arc[start angle=-40,end angle=220,radius=0.6];
      \filldraw[white,line width=\d,rounded corners=2pt] (-40:0.6) rectangle ++(-0.2,-0.35);
      \filldraw[white,line width=\d,rounded corners=2pt] (220:0.6) rectangle ++(0.2,-0.35);
      \end{scope}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newsavebox\myheadphone
  \begin{lrbox}{\myheadphone}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \def\d{5pt}
      \draw[draw=none,fill={rgb,255:red,220; green,150; blue,100}] (0,0) circle (1);
      \begin{scope}[yshift=\d/2]
      \draw[draw=white,line width=\d,line cap=round] (-40:0.6) arc[start angle=-40,end angle=220,radius=0.6];
      \filldraw[white,line width=\d,rounded corners=2pt] (-40:0.6) rectangle ++(-0.2,-0.35);
      \filldraw[white,line width=\d,rounded corners=2pt] (220:0.6) rectangle ++(0.2,-0.35);
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{lrbox}
  \draw[help lines,] (-2, -2) grid[step={(1,1)}] (2, 2);
  \node[draw] (A) at (0,-2){A};

  \path (A) ++(2,2) pic (B) {headphone};

  \node [inner sep=0pt] (C) at (-2,0) {\usebox\myheadphone};

  \draw[->] (A) -- (B-outline);
  \draw[->] (A) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is a scalable version, where the scale parameter can be added as an argument to the `pic`, e.g. `\pic {headphone=2};` to make it twice the size.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{bakcolor}{RGB}{220,150,100}

\tikzset{
  pics/headphone/.style={
    code={
      \def\d{5pt}
      \node[draw=none,fill=bakcolor,minimum size=2cm*#1,circle] (-outline) at (0,0){};
      \begin{scope}[yshift=\d/2*#1]
      \draw[draw=white,line width=\d*#1,line cap=round] (-40:0.6*#1) arc[start angle=-40,end angle=220,radius=0.6*#1];
      \filldraw[white,line width=\d*#1,rounded corners=2pt] (-40:0.6*#1) rectangle ++(-0.2,-0.35*#1);
      \filldraw[white,line width=\d*#1,rounded corners=2pt] (220:0.6*#1) rectangle ++(0.2,-0.35*#1);
      \end{scope}
 }},
 pics/headphone/.default=1,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic {headphone};
  \pic at (3,0) {headphone=2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I use scale=2, the pic will be disordered.

Comment: @lucky1928 Not if you scale the `tikzpicture`. I added a second `pic` version though, where you can specify a scale parameter for the `pic` itself.

Answer (score 5):

I do not understand why you expect that that the *minimum* size option will make the (very nice) picture smaller. You can make it any size by using the  `scale` option instead. For instance

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \definecolor{bakcolor}{RGB}{220,150,100}
  \newsavebox\myheadphone
  \begin{lrbox}{\myheadphone}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \def\d{5pt}
      \draw[draw=none,fill={rgb,255:red,220; green,150; blue,100}] (0,0) circle (1);
      \draw[draw=white,line width=\d,line cap=round] (-40:1) arc (-40:220:1);
      \draw[draw=white,fill=white,line width=\d,rounded corners=2pt] (-40:1) rectangle ++(-0.3,-0.6);
      \draw[draw=white,fill=white,line width=\d,rounded corners=2pt] (220:1) rectangle ++(0.3,-0.6);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{lrbox}
  \draw[help lines,] (-2, -2) grid[step={(1,1)}] (2, 2);
  \node[draw] (A) {A};
  \node[circle,fill=bakcolor,right=1cm of A,scale=0.4] (B) {\usebox\myheadphone};
  \draw[->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

EDIT: After the comment, I believe to understand your question better. If you want to have a fixed size, you may want to steal [this nice macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/how-to-scale-a-tikzpicture-to-textwidth). The complete code is

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\measure@tikzpicture}
\NewEnviron{scaletikzpicturetowidth}[1]{%
  \def\tikz@width{#1}%
  \def\tikzscale{1}\begin{lrbox}{\measure@tikzpicture}%
  \BODY
  \end{lrbox}%
  \pgfmathparse{#1/\wd\measure@tikzpicture}%
  \edef\tikzscale{\pgfmathresult}%
  \BODY
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \definecolor{bakcolor}{RGB}{220,150,100}
  \newsavebox\myheadphone
  \begin{lrbox}{\myheadphone}
    \begin{scaletikzpicturetowidth}{1cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\tikzscale]
      \def\d{5pt}
      \draw[draw=none,fill={rgb,255:red,220; green,150; blue,100}] (0,0) circle (1);
      \draw[draw=white,line width=\d,line cap=round] (-40:1) arc (-40:220:1);
      \draw[draw=white,fill=white,line width=\d,rounded corners=2pt] (-40:1) rectangle ++(-0.3,-0.6);
      \draw[draw=white,fill=white,line width=\d,rounded corners=2pt] (220:1) rectangle ++(0.3,-0.6);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{scaletikzpicturetowidth}
  \end{lrbox}
  \draw[help lines,] (-2, -2) grid[step={(1,1)}] (2, 2);
  \node[draw] (A) {A};
  \node[circle,fill=bakcolor,right=1cm of A] (B) {\usebox\myheadphone};
  \draw[->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem I have with this is that your nice headphone code involves some absolute (or explicit) lengths (such as 5pt). Therefore, this method of scaling the picture does not always yield a nice result.

Comment: Thanks, using scale, it's hard to get exact size (say 1cm).