# Couldn't build example code from tikzscale

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzscale

I'm trying to scale a tikzpicture to `\textwidth` like [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/how-to-scale-a-tikzpicture-to-textwidth). And [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241168/95054) suggests to use package [tikzscale](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzscale).

I follow the document to build an example myself:

```
%example.tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{linewidth.tikz}
\end{document}
```

```
%linewidth.tikz
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) – node {center} (\linewidth,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Compiling with `$ xelatex example.tex`, I got

```
! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.2 \draw (0,0) –
                    node {center} (\linewidth,1);
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: you can try this `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth,1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}`

Comment: BTW: never use the `minimal` class, it is not intended for public use. Use `article` or simular

Comment: Hmm, `tikzscale` is quite old, both tikz and `graphicx` have been updated quite a lot since 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the tikz-file `–` should be `--`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- node {center} (\linewidth,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```