# How to draw the image in beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, axis

I intend to draw the following image in beamer presentation. May you please help me to draw that?

[image]

I intend to use the following code but it gives an error about package. Of course, the code is not complete because I do not know how to identify the line and the area under that in the code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us the code you tried so far ...

Comment: Please show your code and state errors you got.

Comment: If I had a specific code, I would put on that, but I need any help for writing a proper code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this? I am not sure how the grey area should be drawn.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[black!10] (-4,4.5) to[out=0,in=180] (-3,5) -- (5,-3) to[out=180,in=-45] (1,-2) -- (-4,3) -- cycle;
\draw[ultra thick] (-3,5) -- (5,-3) node[above right, midway]{$x_1 + x_2 = y$};

\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-3.9,-3.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[->, ultra thick] (-4,0) -- (5,0) node[right]{$x_1$};
\draw[->, ultra thick] (0,-4) -- (0,5) node[above]{$x_2$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or even more like the original:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[black!20] (-4,4.5) to[out=0,in=180] (-3,5) -- (5,-3) to[out=180,in=-45] (.5,-1.5) -- (-4,3) -- cycle;
\draw[ultra thick] (-3,5) -- (5,-3) node[above right, midway]{$x_1 + x_2 = y$};

\draw[thick] (-4,0) -- (5,0) node[right]{$x_1$};
\draw[thick] (0,-4) -- (0,5) node[above]{$x_2$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you would like to fill the area with a pattern, I would recommend the `patterns` library of Ti*k*Z that needs to be loaded in the preamble of your document (after having loaded the `tikz` package). Please consult chapter 62 of the [Ti*k*Z/PGF documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) regarding the different options.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[pattern=north east lines] (-4,4.5) to[out=0,in=180] (-3,5) -- (5,-3) to[out=180,in=-45] (.5,-1.5) -- (-4,3) -- cycle;
\draw[ultra thick] (-3,5) -- (5,-3) node[above right, midway]{$x_1 + x_2 = y$};

\draw[thick] (-4,0) -- (5,0) node[right]{$x_1$};
\draw[thick] (0,-4) -- (0,5) node[above]{$x_2$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Regarding the grey area, it just shows the area under the line, nothing more

Comment: I put the code on the file, now I have the following errors: Latex error: Environment tikspicture undefined. Missing number, treated as zero. Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). Undefined control sequence. Latex error: \begin{minipage} on input line ended by \end{tikzpicture}

Comment: You need to load Ti*k*Z. Put `\usepackage{tikz}` in your preamble.

Comment: And How can I reduce its size?

Comment: If I want to put some pattern instead of gray color under the line, what should I do?

Comment: As for resizing, please see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6388/47927 . As for the pattern: What kind of pattern do you have in mind?

Comment: hachure, for example a set of parallel lines instead of color

Comment: I prefer the original :-) +1