# Update "How to scale a tikzpicture to \textwidth" for expl3/xparse

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3, xparse, scaling, tikz-external

I am probably the thousandth person who wants to scale a tikzpicture to the size of `\textwidth`.

There is a solution for this problem given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6391/193625
however it uses `environ`. I do not exactly know what that packages offers but it seems that it is redundant with `NewDocumentEnvironment` of `xparse`.

1. Am I correct that `xparse` could/should be used here? Sadly I still understand LaTeX far to little to translate the older solution myself. Any help is appreciated.
2. Does anyone know why this is not implemented directly into `tikz/pgf`?

Ty for your help.

Franz

(I am interested in a solution that works with the `externalize` option of `tikz`.)

Comment: Doesn't `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{...}` do what you want?

Comment: Joseph Wright wrote something comparing the `xparse` solutions against their old counterparts [on his blog](https://www.texdev.net/2020/08/20/newdocumentcommand-versus-newcommand-versus). And yes, you can use `\NewDocumentEnvironment` instead of `\NewEnviron` to use the content of an environment twice. But that's only about defining macros/environments, the usage is not affected (unless `xparse` deals better with catcodes).

Comment: But the externalizing of it is separate from the `xparse` part. `externalize` looks for `\begin{tikzpicture}` Have you tried any of these solutions with `external`? It may produce two PDFs, only the first one (that's too big) or none.

Comment: You know, 99.9% of the time questions like "why does program X not have feature Y" is "the author doesn't have time/think about it" kind of answer... -------- In any case, if I were you and the old answer works I would not care too much about whether the code looks pretty. (unless I want to modify it later) LaTeX kernel has too much "ugly" code already.

Comment: Scaling with `scale` doesn't affect nodes and so relations between parts can change. You often have to make adjustments and to rearrange parts to get a pleasing result and imho a simple automatical solution doesn't exist.